# Handling the answers of Duplicates

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrant-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions) got me thinking. There are problems with the way answers to duplicate questions are handled currently.

### Low quality

There are far too many of these:

> See [here](dup)
>
> You can foo the bar. More info here: [here](answer to dup, maybe by the same person)
>
> See the [manual](manual)

Etc. These are sometimes even upvoted to 10 and accepted.

### Answers everywhere

There are some legit answers to duplicates which unfortunately don't ever get seen, since they're not on the main question. Close as dup is supposed to prevent information being spread across many questions, but answers that get in before closing get to stay.

### Proposal:

Have duplicates with upvoted answers automatically flagged, so the some answers can be deleted (low-quality) or moved (high quality), ones that only answer the duplicate question or aren't good enough to merge should stay.

Comment: Are you proposing merging of questions? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94636/merging-questions  some material on how that process works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75233/simplify-the-merge-question-ui

Comment: @rene Isn't that for self-duplication?

Comment: You said that the answers should be moved (I oppose to deleting). I assume you want to move them to somewhere useful, hence the merging... or am I missing the point?

Comment: @rene I don't want all duplicates to be blindly merged, no. Duplicate's answers are of mixed quality, and some need to be deleted. Some should stay (medium quality, only answers one of the questions, etc.). Some should move.

Comment: OK, maybe clarify that in your question...