# Dead links of deleted questions

Tags: discussion

I come across questions where they are flagged as duplicate and ask me to refer to the another question but when I click on the link it says the question has been deleted. I similarly have this for closed questions too. If its flagged and voted as duplicate why don't they close or delete the duplicate flagged question and leave the one with the already answered on the other side undeleted. If they have a lot of duplicates then they may link them up to the top rep thread. When I see a question as duplicate with a few answers and then move to the question linked in the duplicate question and see it as dead what shall I do?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221619/auto-flag-duplicates-of-deleted-questions-for-reopening-deletion

Comment: Thanks @bjb568. Why don't the questions be merged or sandboxed?

Comment: I don't know. I've [complained before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252198/handling-the-answers-of-duplicates).

Comment: I also a feature request and some solutions of cleaning up the links with some batc job from this thread. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43724/duplicate-of-deleted-post