# How do I get a user to come to meta?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Just now, I invested myself a little more than usual in a [run-of-the-mill, low-quality duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448152/how-can-i-delete-a-specific-character-from-string/).  I flagged it as a duplicate, and of course by the time I'd done that it had already accrued some downvoted answers.  One user "demanded" an explanation and although I did not downvote his (admittedly correct) answer, I linked him to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions/) question in an attempt to try to get the user to understand why not to answer duplicate questions.  I looked at his profile and although he's been an active member for over two years, he's never touched meta.

I can only hope that my two comments referring him here do their job.  In his comments, he claims to legitimately want to help people which is a trait that I find admirable (and I think that most/all of us possess, otherwise why would we be here?).  But who knows if he will even click on my links.

This leads me to my main point--there are great discussions here on meta that are truly relevant to what's happening on SO, that people on SO would benefit from/*should* read. The community bulletin is in a great location and I think/hope that it should bring more people here.  Obviously, though, it doesn't work for everyone.

**How can we get more users to come to meta?**

Comment: You can't force anyone to do anything. We're all contributing content voluntarily.

Comment: You've already left a comment encouraging him to come here. You can't do anything else.

Comment: In other news, the duplicate you guys chose isn't a great one.  It does have the gist, but like all troubleshooting questions on Stack Overflow, it is highly localized to the OP's particular problem.

Comment: Then why add the binding close vote @RobertHarvey?

Comment: Because the question isn't adding any value anyway.  To do this correctly, we need a decent question that can serve as a reference question.

Comment: One doesn't have to do _anything_.

Comment: @Wooble I'm not intending to force everyone (or anyone) to come here as it is a choice to participate in SO in the first place.  I know I personally will not put the effort into commenting on every duplicate question answer I see (and I will definitely not see anywhere near every duplicate post)

Comment: You can lead a horse to meta but ... oh never mind.