# Closing a question as a duplicate, then answering it

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have noticed this happening a few times, and probably the answer is that it's normal and there's nothing we can do about it, but anyways...

I keep seeing high-rep users mark questions as duplicates, but *answer the duplicate anyways*.

Example: [list of array of strings in c#, how to properly use the add method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809039/list-of-array-of-strings-in-c-how-to-properly-use-the-add-method)

One of the same users who marked this as a duplicate answered the question. Isn't this counterproductive? I thought the whole point of marking as a duplicate was to discourage users from asking duplicates, this does the opposite because they got their answer anyways.

Is it appropriate to downvote when I see this happening, even though the answer itself is correct?

**NOTE**: This particular user didn't answer this question after voting to close, he answered it before, when he was unaware of the duplicates.  I am talking about this issue in general, not trying to show everyone an example of an answer to downvote.

Comment: Your link goes to Vlad from Moscow's answer, who did not vote.

Comment: Yeah. It was meant to be on mine.

Comment: Sorry, meant to link to just the question.

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions

Comment: I updated it for you

Answer (score 10):

You have the order wrong there; Patrick voted **after** posting an answer.

What most likely happened is that they started answering, then O. R. Mapper proposed a duplicate and Patrick happened to agree to that so voted to close too.

You cannot assume that Patrick knew about the duplicate when he started answering.

Comment: That is indeed true. Thanks for understanding Martijn.

Comment: Anyway, looks like a fairly hard-to-find duplicate...

Comment: @Deduplicator: indeed. In the same time I already answered it. It's not for the rep, and if someone sees the duplicate I will follow and take the risk of the question being deleted.

Comment: As Savanna commented, that example should strictly be a motivating example; So, this answer is a bit too limited in scope for the question.

Comment: I don't really think it was a hard to find duplicate... O.R. Mapper found 9 nine duplicates or near-duplicates in the space of the same four minutes it took for the question to be answered. At least one of those is an exact duplicate, I only looked through them until I found a suitable one.

Comment: @Deduplicator: then he should include a sample. That will always focus on the question/answer, not the broad question.

Comment: @Savanna: so what keywords do you need to find these? Most of them aren't duplicates. At most the answer is the same.

Answer (score 4):

I think you forget what it means that I voted to close too. Martijn already pointed out that it was not intentional and that I voted *after* answering.

And if looking for the duplicate takes more time than just answering it, I see no harm in it. Especially when such duplicates aren't always easy to find.

By voting to close (as last one, knowing the post is getting closed) I also risk loosing the rep since a closed question can be deleted. That means that all rep gain will be undone.

Comment: Hey, I believe you. Honestly, I wasn't trying to single you out, and I didn't think to try to figure out the timing of your answer vs. duplicate vote. But I've noticed this happening many times, even where the question was very obviously a duplicate. I was asking more in general than to try to be like "look at this user who's doing something I think is wrong!"

Comment: Okay. No problem. But you know when including a sample people going after it. You could at least drop me a comment that the post was being discussed on meta.

Comment: Sorry, will do if I ever link to a post on Meta again.

Comment: No, questions with upvoted answers do *not* get deleted. Upvoted duplicates are also exempt even without answers.

Comment: Of course the intentions can be misinterpreted, simply because of the fact that after the question is closed noone else can answer it.

Comment: @Patrick: missed that point. That would be really evil.

Comment: @Martijn: then I misunderstood. So only other closed questions can be deleted?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: see [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for all the details on when a post is auto-deleted. Basically only if the OP account was deleted.