# Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I've seen a few users with a gold badge in a tag answer a question, and then immediately close the question as duplicate.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509772) of a question which it happened on (**EDIT**: The answer has been removed, and is now only viewable to users with 10k+ reputation. This question is not only about this one post, but about all posts that this happens on).

The problem with this is that it probably cannot be solved. If I was in the same position, I would probably answer the question before closing it, to make sure the user gets a good answer.

There's already been something discussed about this on [Closing a question as a duplicate, then answering it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265957), but that had to do with voting to close the question, this was done without any voting, due to the mighty Mjölnirs being able to close/reopen questions without voting.

I personally don't see anything wrong with this, as long as the user isn't doing it for personal gain (it would be fine if they made the answer community wiki). Are there any guidelines on what gold-badge users supposed to do with respect to this?

Comment: I see **a lot** wrong with this.  Those wielders of the dupe hammer now have an advantage to answering questions as opposed to those that don't.  I'm siding with Bill on this; if it's a dupe, just close it.  If you answered it in error, there's really no shame in deleting it yourself later.

Comment: I hoped this would never come back at me... I totally agree with you *if the intentions are bad*. It certainly looks that way if you answer and vote to close, in either way, as I have found out myself. If your intentions were okay the 'rule' seems to be: remove your answer, or don't vote. This to take away all grounds to accuse you of foul play.

Comment: Whenever I see an answer coupled by a downvote by the only person submitting the answer, I always downvote the answer.  I encourage everyone else to do the same.

Comment: @Deduplicator - When a question gets closed, it shows who voted to close it.  I meant "vote to close", not "downvote".  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I see no answers on that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509772) :/

Comment: @DavidPostill It seems like it was removed, There was an answer from the same user that closed the question before, though. I'll see it I can find another example.

Comment: Is it really reasonable to assume users with a gold badge in a tag are still trying to farm rep by answering bad questions?  (I can't see the linked question, so I can't judge for myself in this particular case.)

Comment: I've done this many times, but not because I'm trying to farm rep. Unless it's in my list of canonical duplicates, it takes time to find duplicates. Often it's easier to answer the question first, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29612854/1491895. After I post the answer to provide quick help to the OP, I then go searching for the duplicate. Then I close the question to keep SO clean. Should I delete my answer when I do this, to avoid the bad impression?

Comment: I think this is a broader issue. I often see people answer and then vote to close. To me, that seems counter-intuitive and abusive. Answering a question should strip close vote capability and vice-versa.

Comment: great question!!! Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332618/guideline-for-closing-questions-as-duplicate-with-gold-badge/332619

Comment: "it probably cannot be solved". Eh no, actually it can be easily solved if SE stops being so soft. When a user (gold badge or otherwise) votes to close, his answer, if any, to that question should be *automatically deleted* with a penalty of 5 reputation. This is because if the question was worth closing, then the user has no business posting an answer to it. The reputation and the answer is restored if the user retracts his close vote. But SE cannot do such a trivial thing because that would offend certain golden repwhores.

Comment: @MaskedMan, why the penalty? It seems to me the problem is adequately fixed by simply deleting the answer. Whatever repwhoring may be going on, the auto-deletion of the answer will take care of.

Comment: @JohnnyBones, if you start voting based on the person rather than the answer, you're opening up a can of worms (in Oz, this is called playing the man instead of the ball, and is rarely a good thing). I think the better thing to do is vote to close then delete the question for whatever reason you have. Deletion of the question will automatically revert any rep gain from people behaving badly, yes?

Comment: @paxdiablo It is not "adequately" fixed, that is the whole point of the penalty. Let's say you are a golden repwhore, you post an answer, then close the question. Either the question gets deleted or it doesn't. In the former case, you lose nothing, in the latter case, you gain some points. So there is nothing to deter you from golden repwhoring. By introducing a penalty, you have to weigh the risks of gaining points versus losing points when you go golden repwhoring.

Comment: @MaskedMan, perhaps I wasn't clear. I consider your suggestion that, if you vote to close a question, your *answer* is auto-deleted, a good one. This means that there is *no* way to gain rep from a question you vote to close since whatever rep you may have gained is lost on your answer being deleted. The penalty seems superfluous in that case. In a world where crime is impossible, penalties are unnecessary :-)

Comment: @MaskedMan, there'll need to be some extra assurances to stop gaming of course. 1/ These auto-deleted answers cannot be undeleted unless the close-vote is withdrawn. 2/ You cannot answer a question if you have a currently active close-vote. 3/ Whatever else it takes to get it to work :-)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it in general. I do it all the time by accident. If there is a suggestion that it is done for gaming in any one instance, that needs to be proven before action is taken. The system must not act on a presumption of guilt.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I think it's bad form to answer a question then **immediately** close it as a duplicate. If it's a duplicate, just close it. By answering it then immediately closing it, it sends a signal that you're hoping for upvotes on your answer, while depriving others of the opportunity to answer as well. That's not a very level playing field. The dupe hammer is intended to get duplicate questions closed faster, not closed right after gold badge owners can post an answer.

---

Having said that (a few years ago), I will add that it's important to look at the timeline of events before we jump to the conclusion that someone is tactically close voting.

Several times I've answered a question after a cursory search, then noticed that someone else found a canonical version and cast a close vote. I then added my close vote, since I think that's the right thing to do. I'll usually delete my answer and repost it on the original question in those cases (if my answer adds anything), but it's not strictly necessary to do that. (For example, if you're pointing out exactly what line of code is causing an exception on a duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), it doesn't really make sense to move that answer.)

Comment: This happens fairly often in some tags.  I almost think that if they post an Answer, then their VTC is of normal weight for that Q, but thats probably a lot of work to implement.

Comment: @Plutonix That's not a bad idea, even for moderators.

Comment: @Plutonix I agree, but there might be a workaround (problem)..: [This answer was posted *after* the question was closed, how is that possible?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible)

Comment: @Plutonix Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The workaround I was referring to was from a gold badgers POW. He/she could just start sketching a new answer, close the question and post the answer. Right?

Comment: In my view the key word in Bill's answer is **immediately**. There are times when finding a good duplicate isn't all that easy (or) the answerer was not even aware it was a duplicate till answering the question. In such cases, I don't think the VTC is bad after answering the question. It is just that the usage should be a fair attempt to improve the site rather than for personal gains (Note: I didn't intend to say that this was the motive of the answerer in this case.)

Comment: Assume good faith. I can easily imagine how one would answer a question and in the process of improving it (good writing is rewriting), discover a duplicate question. The mere act of answering the question might produce an insight, a deeper understanding of the problem that allows to select a duplicate that hasn't been obvious otherwise.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That was an obvious duplicate of a question that gets asked on SO every single day. It's easily recognized by anyone active in the Java tag.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: the question as I understand it is not about the single example. Your answer seems to be more general too. My comment is not about the java question but about how *"Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate"* could happen with no ill intent.

Comment: If the answer is useful, the original question poster is better off. With closing the question as a duplicate, further fragmentation is inhibited. The only downside you mention concerns imaginary internet points. Surely those don't matter.

Comment: @Cactus That reeks of rationalization. If the question is a duplicate, then yet another answer is not useful. Everyone is better off if we don't waste time answering the question again when we know it's already been answered thoroughly on the canonical Q&A. If imaginary internet points don't matter, then we don't need to game the system to amass a few more.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I've done this myself quite a bit, with no bad intentions at all. I've answered the question, and after that, see someone else vote to close the question as a duplicate. Seeing someone else vote to close happens to often be right after posting an answer, because I just don't notice it while I'm writing an answer, I only notice it after I post the answer. If I agree that it's a duplicate, I'll also vote to close, regardless of whether that instantly closes the question.

Comment: @hvd Sure, there's nothing wrong with that. I've done that myself a few times. It looks suspicious when the person who posts the only answer also casts the only close vote right after they post that answer, though. It makes me think they knew all along that it was a duplicate. (That, and the fact that it's possibly the most duplicated Java question on the site.)

Comment: So, looking at the edit history.  The answerer posted a short answer -- the `==` vs `.equals` problem.  Probably best to mark it as duplicate.  13 minutes later, the answerer edited their answer to include a link to a Q&A on the topic, plus added a bunch of comments saying what else is wrong with the OP's code.  1 minute after editing their answer to mention the duplicate, the answerer marked the question as a duplicate.  I see some laziness (typing an answer rather than finding the canonical one), but little evidence of bad faith, and the answer might help the OP *even with* the dupe flag.

Comment: @Yakk Really? That edit history says "no bad faith" to you? The answerer knew immediately that this was just a duplicate of the == vs. .equals problem, but still spent 13 minutes editing their answer into shape before closing the question.

Comment: @bill answered quickly with something helpful.  Then went back and found other problems, including the canonical duplicate?  (we do not know *when* the canonical dupe was found in those 13 minutes).  Everything in the answer looked like something that would help the OP, no?  And wrote both the useful advice, and a link to dupe, then now that they had the dupe, used the dupe hammer.  Simply marking as a duplicate would be *less useful* than what the answerer did to both future searchers and the OP, until you deleted it.

Comment: @Yakk As I've already said, that question is instantly recognizable as a duplicate of *the most duplicated* Java question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know this is an old question, and I was about to ask a new one. Is there someway to stop this bad practice? I'm seeing it a lot in angular2, A LOT.

Comment: @EricMartinez Unfortunately, there's not much that can be done against it. If you see one person doing it a lot you might comment with a link to this post, but there isn't really an official policy against the behavior.

Comment: If I see someone doing this, should I do something? Flag for moderation attention? Make a post on meta?

Comment: @1615903 If it's just one post, I'd comment with a link to this question. If you notice that they have a pattern of this behavior, I think it would be ok to flag a mod and ask them to warn the user about it.

Answer (score 7):

That's perhaps a bad example. The answer there was just a short summary of the canonical duplicate. It elaborates with a lot of style advise on the concrete code OP presented - which however wasn't relevant to the question at hand.

The alternatives would have been:

- Posting the answer as comment before/after closing. And posting the stylistic advice as lengthy comments as well.
- Not closevoting the question.
- Posting the answer as community wiki. (Which might be acceptable for debugging questions in a few cases. But really not generally.)
- Adding more concrete advice to OPs specific case as answer to the canonical duplicate. But that's seldomly practical. Definitely not in this case.

All but the CW option (also mostly frowned on to circumvent the rules / community practice) would have been even worse in this instance.

Comment: Why is the CW option frowned upon?

Comment: CW is mostly meant for collaborative answers. It was historically overused [as carte blanche](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) to answer off-topic questions. (But might have been borderline ok in OPs case - to avoid locking out other answer contributions after the dupehammer.)

Answer (score -5):

I got linked here because [I did the exact same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304062/append-to-list-in-python/50304080#50304080) - the questions is a variant of the "I added a list to a list in a loop and afterwards it contains the same list n times) - just with the twist of adding dicts to the list.

I voted to close as dupe of [how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) and answered with a code example and a solution to explain the similarity - and as I thought I got

> @Patrick Artner, i do not want to copy any list. i want to create new list with dictionary.

as comment because the reasoning for marking this as dupe was not instantly clear to the question owner.

The reasoning for me is:

- if marked as dupe it can be deleted down the road
- by me answering with a code example the owner gets helped along now

To make it clear,  I do not answer "all" dupes I mark, just if I want to add some code to explain the reasoning behind me "duping" it - and that only if it does not fit into a comment.

Question is deleted and the person who linked me here retracted his comment on my answer...

I do not have the "close-hammer" - I just vote to close, so its mabye different than the original case here.

Answer (score -6):

I find myself doing that sometimes for various reasons.

- A common one is often I feel I can explain stuff better in an answer tailored to the OP's specific situation, rather than just pointing them to a generic answer somewhere else.
- Another is that I'm not positive it's a duplicate until I post an answer and the OP confirms in either a comment or an accepted answer.
- And sometimes I don't see or remember the duplicate until afterwards.

At a certain point, rep no longer becomes a thought or motivating factor in anything on SO, and I would be surprised if high-rep users were doing this just for rep.

I write answers to help people with their problems, and I suspect that's what the user was trying to do with their answer in your example case. They are explaining the problem in more detail using the OP's code as an example, and then closing it as a duplicate afterwards to help keep the site clean.

Personally I don't think their answer should be deleted by a mod, as it seems very helpful to the OP since it's tailored for them and their code, and I sincerely doubt anyone with 298K rep is doing it just to gain 10 or 25 extra points.

Comment: Many of the people who have lots of rep have lots of rep *precisely* because they care a *lot* about getting rep.  Not all of them, to be sure, but certainly some.

Comment: Help me understand the metrics in *closing it as a duplicate afterwards to help keep the site clean*.  One answer (yours) is still clean, but other answers are bad?  It is not about anyone's intentions (and the linked answer is both general and tailored to the OP); but if one person can respond, others ought to be able to as well.  Many dupes have some niche element to them, but more than one response ought be allowed.

Comment: @Plutonix I answer questions to help people, not to help SO. I do try to keep SO "clean" because I like the platform, but that's not my primary purpose for reading/answering questions. For example, if I know its recommended to close questions as a duplicate one well-written version of the question I'll do that. But if I think OP needs some extra explanation based on their specific code, I am likely to post an answer explaining it to them first (assuming it doesn't fit in a comment), and vote to close it afterwards.

Comment: @Servy The user who posted that answer has 288,664 rep. I've been on the site for a few years, and spent my fair share of time in the "I'm addicted to answering questions" stage, but I only have 54k. I can't image the time and effort it would take to get 298k, and I can't imagine still caring enough about rep to be concerned over every 10 or 25 points after that long of a time. Based on what I see of that user's answer and other activity, he's only interested in helping the OP and trying to be a good "SO citizen" along the way.

Comment: @Rachel And yet you generalized your assumptions about that one user to *every* "high rep" user in your answer.  I'm not familiar enough with that user to comment on them personally, but I most certainly have interacted with users that people have considered to be "high rep" users that were very concerned about earning more rep, contrary to what you've said in your answer.

Comment: I'll also refer you to [this other post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286211/1159478).  If the related question doesn't actually answer the question that the OP has, then the question just isn't a duplicate.  It's asking for something suitably different that it requires additional information/context not in the answers of the other question.  In such a case, the question should not be closed.  If no additional information/context is necessary to answer the question, then it's a duplicate,e should be closed as such, and no answer is needed.

Comment: @Servy Honestly I don't think the example question should be closed as a duplicate, as if you examine the (now deleted) example answer, it addresses other problems with the OPs code instead of just the incorrect string comparism. So I agree with you there. :)

Comment: @Rachel So if you don't think the question should be closed, then why are you arguing that he should be able to both answer it and close it?

Comment: @Servy I was actually posting this as a comment, but it got too long. I wanted to share what my reasons had been during the times I recall posting an answer and closing as a duplicate afterwards. I didn't like the presumed asumption was immediately that the user was doing it to gain rep or close out other answerers, as that's never been a case for me even though I know I've used my gold badge to close questions as dups after answering in the past. And I really didn't like the fact the answer had been deleted by a mod, as it seemed more useful to the OP than the linked duplicate.