# How should you answer a question that is almost a duplicate, but not quite?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

Suppose I notice a question is a duplicate, and I vote to close it.  But the duplicate question is only very similar, not exactly the same.

Is it acceptable/appropriate to include code from the more-accepted question to answer the question you marked as a duplicate?

[Here is an example of the situation I've come across.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550538/how-do-i-get-unobtrusive-validation-to-work/28550582#28550582)

I have linked to the other question and made it clear I did not write the original so as to avoid plagiarism - but is this enough?  Should the question just be closed with no answers?

Comment: Oh the irony.  Thanks, I did not find those in my search.  I will *ahem* mark mine as a dupe. :)

Comment: @Deduplicator I think I could rephrase this so it is not the same - take a look again in a moment

Answer (score 6):

Exactly one of the following two statements is true:

1. The duplicate question has answers that answer the OP's question.
2. The duplicate question does not have answers that answer the OP's question.

If #1 is true, the question is a duplicate.  Vote to close and don't answer it.  If you would like to add additional information to the original question, you're welcome to improve that resource by editing the existing answers or adding your own answer.

If #2 is true then the question isn't a suitable duplicate, and you shouldn't be  voting to close the question.  You're welcome to add an answer if you have one.

If the questions are fundamentally asking the same thing, and the reason that the existing question doesn't answer the current question is that is has no answers, or the existing answers are incorrect/low quality, then you're welcome to answer either question and close the other as a duplicate of the question that now has a quality correct answer.  If you can't answer either, feel free to comment with a link to the related question, even though they can't be closed.

If there are subtle differences in the questions that change the correct answer, then they're not duplicates.  Consider editing the questions to make the differences more apparent to readers, if it's not already clear, so that readers will understand what the related question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: My situation is closer to "Q1 answers Q2, but I can extract a small part of Q1 to more exactly answer Q2" - if that makes sense

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 To me closing a more specific question as a duplicate of a broader question is fine, as anyone with the more specific question can find an answer to their question in the broader question, at least within reason; if you honestly feel that someone asking the more specific question would be able to understand the answer to the broader question and solve their problem, close.

Comment: makes sense.  I edited my question so that it's more of the "what if the answer is not an exact duplicate, but very close" question.

Comment: Then you use your judgement - it's either a dupe or it isn't. But it you can copy from another answer and paste to answer the new question, that should be a serious red flag that it *is* a duplicate.

Comment: How can I answer questions that are `borderline duplicates` (but still not duplicates), if my answer for both questions is essentially the same, without being reprimanded for it?! Or what other options do I have? See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315293/answering-borderline-duplicate-questions

Comment: @JohnSlegers Either the answers *are* the same, in which case, you vote to close, or they aren't, and you post answers that specifically address each question, since neither answer would suitably answer the other question.