# Deleted duplicate answers policy

Tags: discussion

The moderator deleted an answer because I added my answer to all the questions that my answer could possible solve. So now people will not see a possible fix, which I spent half the day trying to figure out. A duplicate answer for multiple questions is hardly a problem.

Also, why should I continue to waste my time if some moderator deletes my post?

I think the policy is [BS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bullshit#English). They should at least add a link before deleting. Can you link to another answer?

Comment: If your answer fits multiple questions, it's an incredibly strong indicator the questions are duplicates. You should be flagging the questions as duplicates instead, or tailoring your answers to the specific questions if the questions aren't duplicates. (If you did that, then they wouldn't be duplicate answers.)

Comment: sometimes, some question have many possible fixes and vise versa

Comment: better to side with caution, to possible help a person trying to find the answer

Comment: so one question was viewed over 37K, and my fixed worked for two people, and could possible helped many more, but NOOOO duplicates! it's BS!

Comment: Stay civil, as per our [help center be nice policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Stop with the name calling, @eschneider - I've already edited that out of your question and deleted one comment.

Comment: *"... I spent half the day trying to figure out"*; *"A duplicate answer for multiple questions is hardly a problem."* Well you would probably spend also half a day editing all your posted answers if you just want to change, update or improve something.

Comment: It *is* possible that the same answer could be posted to two (or more) questions that are *not* duplicates, but this is quite rare. Since you didn't give any concrete example in your question, it's a bit difficult for most of the community to weigh in on the matter. I would recommend that you edit the question to provide a concrete example (e.g. which answer did you post on which questions?)

Comment: look, I spent half a day trying to solve this problem, and three of these questions have identical errors. My answer (The same exact answer) could possibly fix all three question. Then some moderator deletes it, and I have no simple recourse and people are potentially wasting time.

Comment: @eschneider You *absolutely* have a recourse.  Since all three questions have the same problem, you should vote to close all but the best as duplicates of the best one, and post your answer *once* on that one canonical question.  That's exactly what the moderator's message explained to you.

Comment: I agree that is ideal, but it may not be apparent, and who am I to say there's not some minor difference that's important. I added an answer to dupe answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339183/117499

Comment: @eschneider Since you don't have 3k rep, you're right, you *don't* have the right to say that there aren't relevant differences between the posts.  When you have 3k rep, you will be able to vote to close, and *then* you will have the ability to assert that you feel that there aren't any *relevant* differences in the questions, and if 5 people agree, the question will be closed.  If you end up earning a gold badge for any of the tags for a question, then you will be considered sufficiently knowledgeable about the topic to, by yourself, determine if the questions have any relevant differences.

Answer (score 25):

> A duplicate answer for multiple questions is hardly a problem.

A duplicate answer for multiple questions suggests that the questions are duplicates of each other.

The right course of action is not to answer them all, but close them as duplicates of a canonical question with a good answer.

Comment: that's not always true, some of these errors are used for multiple problems

Comment: @eschneider - usually it is the case. Though, if you say "multiple problems", that suggests to me that there should be *different* answers.

Comment: @eschneider If you can copy and paste the exact answer then it is 99.9% true.  If you fell they are not duplicates then you should tailor the answer to each unique question.

Comment: Scientific observation: when a specific deleted answer is brought up on Meta with a "my answer was deleted this policy is BS!!!!" statement the probability that it was an exact duplicate rises to 99.99999999%

Comment: The fact that one question has *exactly the same answer* as another question is the *definition* of a duplicate question. That's literally how we tell.

Comment: Just like CodyGray said. That's why the text on questions that were closed as duplicate says "This question already has an answer here" instead of "this question already exists here". It's about the same answer, not about the same question.