# Mistaken deleted answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I believe a moderator has made a mistake in his moderation of this answer:

*[Pandas cannot open an Excel (.xlsx) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-xlsx-file/65266497#65266497)*

The answer is similar to this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65266270/216229

...but I have actually already done what he has requested: you'll note the suggested code change is different for each of the different answers. I'm afraid this answer cannot be tailored any more, since the rest of the answer is genuinely the same.

For background, I'm the maintainer of the package emitting these errors, and I'm already working with the Pandas folk to make their package emit clearer instructions when this code path is hit.

Comment: Looks like you posted duplicate answers which triggered the mod flag... which also means the question is highly possible a duplicate and should be closed instead of answered.

Comment: When solutions are basically the same why wouldn't you vote to close one and point at answer in the other?

Comment: Relevant: [Answering “borderline duplicate” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315293/11682469)

Comment: @charlietfl - because I don't use stackoverflow that much, I just maintain python libraries ;-)

Comment: @AndrewT. - you are correct, I've now flagged the lower quality question as a duplicate, unfortunately my answer was deleted on the higher quality question.

Comment: There was an automatic duplicate-answer flag raised by the system on the answer which was deleted. It was raised at the same time the answer was posted. That means the system saw a version which was *identical* to the other answer. Given that there's no other version recorded for the answer that was deleted, that implies you saved an initial version and then made a grace period edit to update the code in the answer which was deleted. Given that the edit was a grace period edit, there would have been no notation in the flag handling UI that the post had been edited.

Comment: @Makyen - that sounds like exactly what happened - the first part of the answer is identical, so I copied the source, must have accidentally hit save, but then edited it to change the advice to tailor it for that specific question. How can I get this answer undeleted? (even if it means deleting the other answer...)

Comment: Looks like this has been un-deleted, so thanks to whoever that was!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is an unfortunate delete.

You did indeed tailor both of these answers to their questions. Based on the timeline none of those answers have been in a recorded state where they were the same. As it turns out by [a comment from Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403645/mistaken-deleted-answer#comment814128_403645) the moderators attention was brought to those answer due to an automatic flag that was immediately raised when you submitted the identical answer that you then edited in the grace period to its current state.

I can't judge for 100% if the questions are duplicate but no-one yet found that the case as no close votes in that direction had been fired at the time of writing. (A duplicate vote has been cast by the OP now).

In my opinion the answer shouldn't have been deleted. A moderator flag on the answer should be raised, explain the case and ask for un-deletion. Linking to this meta post might help in that case. You'll find the *flag* link directly under your answer, next to *share*, *edit*, *follow* and *(un)delete*. Click it and select *in need of moderator intervention*. Use the presented textbox to its full capacity (iow elaborate).