# Should users be permitted to both answer and close a question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I just read [Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate) and the following question occurred to me: Should it be permitted for users to both:

- answer the question
- cast a close vote

All close reasons indicate that the question is for one reason or another not suitable for the site, so we're not looking for *new answers* to that question. If it's a duplicate, then there are answers elsewhere.

What I'm thinking are two new rules:

1. If the user has cast a close vote (even if the question has not been actually closed), they are no longer permitted to answer the question. If they want to answer the question, they'll have to retract their close vote first.
2. If the user has answered the question, they cannot cast a close vote. If they want to cast a close vote, they'll have to delete their answer first.

I guess a third rule is the user shouldn't be permitted to *undelete* their deleted answer after casting a close vote.

This proposal would prevent gold badge users from answering the question and then invoking the dupehammer to prevent other users from answering.

Comment: The other option is to just raise an automatic mod flag, and have them look into the issue, possibly deleting the answer, merging the questions, reopening the question, or whatever.

Comment: @Servy: That sounds like more workload for mods.

Comment: @GregHewgill If it's what it takes to handle the situation correctly, that's what it takes.  If no automatic action can be decided on as the correct course of action, enabling manual intervention is sometime the next best option.

Comment: @Servy: I just can't think of a situation where a user can legitimately both answer *and* close a question. I know I've done it, but I probably should have deleted my answer when I decided to vote to close.

Comment: @GregHewgill You answer it first. Then you discover a dupe later on and close it. Though in that case, you might consider deleting your answer as well.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yes, but what *should* be done?  Should the answer be deleted, the question closed, the questions merged, etc.?  Even if you know that what happened was wrong, it may not be clear what actually *should* happen.  This is the case for the majority of the existing automated flags.  The system knows something is wrong, and that some action needs to be taken, but a human needs to determine what the correct response is.  If it turns out that there is only one correct response, then a mod flag would indeed be unnecessary.

Comment: @Mysticial That or merging.

Comment: Close reasons don't all imply total unsuitability, some imply _long term unsuitability_ hidden behind the generic term "off topic".  A question may still be answerable, even if it's a crappy question. This is why "Too Localized" was abused, and eventually removed, and this is why the "typo or no longer reproducible" off topic reason exists now. You can still answer the question, and still downvote and closevote it, help the OP, and kick it into the Roomba's path.  The downvotes and eventual closing indicate to the OP that it was a poor question.

Comment: Sometimes I answer a question, after which someone points out it is a duplicate. I agree and vote to close the post. Nothing untowards here, but now suddenly I have to delete my answer first. I just helped the OP, now I have to take that away to dupe-vote to keep the site reasonably clean. I'm not sure that that is productive.

Comment: So instead what I fear will happen is that answerers will be *far less inclined* to close vote a post with this change in place.

Comment: Sometimes good questions get posted to SO, when they might be a better fit on Superuser or Serverfault.  In that situation, I don't see anything wrong with answering, then voting to migrate.

Comment: I dunno... Is this really an exploitable thing?  Because if it is, I'm totally in.  For exploiting it, I mean.  I just don't see it as one...

Comment: I would consider this an edge case that should just be flagged for mod attention if exploited.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski If a question is a low quality quesiton that the site has determined shouldn't be answered as those types of questions cause more problems than they solve, then one should not encourage answering it and voting to close.  The whole point of voting to close it is to say that the question shouldn't be answered (here).

Comment: @Servy Point of voting to close is sometimes to say that the question _should be improved_. And if it can be, it's spiteful to withhold answers in those cases. Downvotes+closure encourage the OP to improve - and if the question is improved, it can be reopened and might contribute lasting value to the site. In practice do I answer & close? No except for maybe one or two mistakes in the past year.

Comment: @Servy That sounds an awful lot like coming to a conclusion before there is actual consensus. Not all questions with a close vote end up being closed, and taking action to discourage answers before the consensus is reached is counter productive.

Comment: It shouldn't be *too* hard to whip up a data.SE to find out how many people close questions with answers too and see if this is a small or big problem.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I suppose my statement was incomplete, as is so often the case of a summary.  One votes to close questions that shouldn't be answered *in their current state*, and to which answering them *as they are* would cause more problems than they would solve.

Comment: @TravisJ That is a valid argument for why it's okay for someone to answer a question someone else (but not five others) has voted to close.  But if you are voting to close the question, it is because you personally feel that (as the question stands) it would be better off for it to not be answered.  Answering it is thus a contradiction.

Comment: Related - one can retract close votes.  One can't retract flags. Can a person with less than 3k rep flag a question as XYZ, (have it edited), and then answer? Or should they be under the restriction that they can't answer if they've flagged (or flag once they've answered and the question morphed)?  Which also brings up the morphing question problem - you answer it, it morphs to another with more info and becomes a clear cut dup.

Comment: @Servy - I was addressing the discouraging answers aspect in general. I agree that if the scenario is you are voting to close, then answering it is more than likely contradictory. However, I am not convinced about how to solve the latter situation where you answer and then decide to vote to close for some reason or another that you discover once the answer was posted.

Comment: @TravisJ Just silently delete the answer instead of preventing the close vote ;)

Comment: @Servy - It doesn't seem to make sense to delete every answer to every closed question.

Comment: And if other answers to closed questions are not the issue, then what makes the one new answer different?

Comment: I had a recent case of answering a question about a particularly obscure topic that turned out to have been asked exactly once, just a month before - with tons of upvotes but an answer that didn't provide much information precisely because the topic was so obscure. In my case, the questions were identical so I ended up merging them with permission from the user who originally answered as they favored my answer over theirs. The reason I answered the new question on the spot was because I honestly didn't expect it to have been asked before, and I figured I was in the best position to answer it.

Comment: I guess the takeaway in my case is to never assume a question hasn't been asked before, no matter how obscure the topic may be.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, and that sounds like it's exactly the use case that merging is there for.  If one answers a question only to later realize it's a duplicate, merging is often the correct course of action, unless the recently added answer is just adding no additional value to the existing answers (or vice versa).

Comment: @BoltClock - Us normal-folk can't merge like that though :) And it had never really occurred to me to flag for a moderator with a merge request. Should there be more merging?

Comment: @Travis J: Yeah, it's totally fine to flag to ask for a merge. But merging is only done when the questions are word-for-word identical or the answers will make sense in the context of either question without having to edit them all to suit the merge destination - because merging is for the most part irreversible.

Comment: Anybody who has enough rep to wield a dupehammer isn't going to be motivated by a mere 25 points. If somebody's leaving an answer and voting to close as well, I assume they have good reasons. I know I've done it myself, although no examples jump to mind.

Comment: I often answer a question, and then later see it in the review queue. I've no particular compunction about voting to close in that circumstance.

Comment: Is there an easy way for me to find questions that I've both answered and close-voted? I'm betting I've done it at least once, but of course I can't explain why without finding it . . .

Comment: I do answer and close questions a bunch. The reason for it is to help the user. Yes it is a dupe, but the OP might not know how to apply it directly to their code. So I give them the answer based off the dupe. I also have the mighty hammer so it closes it. A lot of the time I get "it is not a dupe" angry comment and have to explain how it applies. This way, I stop getting the angry comments. Personally, I would rather put the code in the comments and not an answer, but you know how crappy a few lines of code appears so it is useless.

Comment: What exactly would you expect the impact of this change to be? I can understand the idea behind preventing the malicious behavior, however, how do you know the user was being malicious? he/she very well could have provided an answer, then realized it was a dupe and closed it. If' it's a dupe, it definitely should be closed regardless of whether or not you provided an answer.

Comment: There's also the possibility of the user simply wanted to provide a more targeted answer for this op, even though the question was answered in another question on a broader level (for example, the ajax is asynchronous or for loop closure canonicals.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, absolutely these users should be allowed to both answer and vote to close.

Users who gain rep also gain privileges on the site because we trust they know more about how the site is used, and we want them to help us maintain it.

**By doing this, you would be limiting the maintenance potential of some of your most active userbase - the answerers.**

Just because a user answered a while ago, doesn't mean that later on they shouldn't be able to vote to close (as a duplicate or otherwise) as new information emerges, or site rules change, or a better question is discovered.

Keep in mind that most questions require 3 close votes (formerly 5) to get closed, so in many cases a single user does not have the power to both answer and immediately close the question. The only exception is moderators, and gold-badge users if they are voting to close as a duplicate.

So basically you would be putting in a limiting mechanism to make it *harder* for users to maintain the site, in exchange for the potential that our "trusted users" *may* try to ... Stop others from gaining rep instead of them? Gain an extra 25ish rep from a closed question? I don't even know.

And as a side note, I answer because I like to help users. If given the choice between writing a detailed version of an answer with examples specific to the OP's code, vs closing as a duplicate to something generic that the OP may or may not understand, I will vote to answer and leave open every time.

Comment: Thank you for that last paragraph. It's become such an uncommon viewpoint in the past few years and even wins scorn from some segments of the community.

Comment: I will sometimes give a brief, succinct answer that covers the immediate points of the question, and then go hunt down the detailed duplicate, and subsequently vote to close (assuming I can actually find the duplicate, which is usually not as easy as I'd like).  I don't do it to get rep, or prevent other people getting rep.  I do it so the OP gets a sufficient answer to get them on their way, and the question ends up closed as a duplicate of a question with a good (usually far longer) answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I couldn't agree more. There's been so much emphasis in the newer rules over the past few years on trying to get the perfect canonical question and treating SO as a sacrosanct knowledge repository, that we've seem to ignore the fact that people often simply answer to help others. SO's main drive is its Q&A flow, not its curation aspect. Sometimes it feels like the [SO motto](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) "*Ask questions, get answers, no distractions*" has been forgotten.

Comment: @Bruno Parts of meta and some tag-specific chatrooms have become echo chambers in that regard - it's super frustrating to those of us who still spend most of our time actually in the trenches trying to help users improve their questions to be answerable, stave off more downvotes or actually answer. Like wartime medics running between the wounded while snipers shoot at them.  Except, you know, not really anything like that at all :-)

Comment: Hello Rachel! Maybe it's me not contributing enough, but I haven't seen you around. It's great to see your insightful answers again.

Comment: @Ben Thanks! I haven't been as active lately on StackExchange... I started a new job a year or so ago and it doesn't have anywhere near the downtime my old job had, which was usually my SE-browsing time :)

Comment: I'm guessing you don't run into Android questions where there are 5 different answers each with a good amount of "it works for me" and "it doesn't work for me" comments attached to each answer!

Comment: *Just because a user answered a while ago, doesn't mean that later on they shouldn't be able to vote to close* - you only addressed the question in one way. How about *Voting to close* then *answer*? Or the other way around, but within a few minutes/hours?

Answer (score 19):

> This proposal would prevent gold tag users from answering the question and then invoking the dupehammer **to prevent** other users from answering. <sup>emphasis mine</sup>

The wording implies that evil lurks in the heart of the closer. I try not to make windows into the souls of men to divine their intentions.  But, whether intentional or not, the fact is that answering then closing (not simply voting to close, but slamming the door shut), does in fact freeze out other answers.

Either it is a dupe and should be closed; or it presents enough of an edge case -- or has an interesting aspect -- that it is worth answering.  In the case of the latter, it ought not be closed.

Sometimes the answers are good (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25017542/302677) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28510426/1070452) (a crap *question* IMO)) in addressing the immediate *and* broader or other issues.  But that is not always the case.  More often I see the opposite: a 5 line answer very narrowly addressing the local issue, then an immediate dupe close by a gold badger.   On more than one occasion I have had an answer composed to offer an alternative approach or offer some degree of explanation and not been able to post it because the question was now closed.

As a matter of principle, it seems oligarchical to condone the practice of answering *and* closing.  I would propose that **if a gold-tagger answers, any vote to close they cast reverts to 1 of 5 needed for that question.**  If it is simpler to prevent a close vote at all, I am fine with that.

If a question is worthy of one answer, the site is not dirtied or made less perfect by more than one.

Even answering and VTC seems a little off kilter, but unless it is a well known dupe (like NRE) it usually takes enough time to get closed that anyone on hand who wants to weigh in can do so.

<sub>Note: the term 'rep' was not used in this answer.  Well, until now.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

- I agree with #1.

In my opinion, if a user casts a vote for closure they should probably not answer the question.

- I disagree with #2.

If a user has answered, they should still be able to cast a close vote.

There are two many corner cases to handle for this to be viable without causing too much strain on either moderators or the use of the feature in general. Not to mention the amount of effort it would take to implement all of the handling for the corner cases.

Further, if the answer is of value it seems counter productive to delete it. Historically if this were applied to closed questions it would result in far too many useful answers being removed. It would also not make sense to differentiate only from new answers as there is fundamentally no difference between the two sets (that of historical versus currently answered but wanting to close vote).

Comment: Please note that I am *not* suggesting that any of these new rules be applied retroactively to old questions.

Comment: @GregHewgill - Why draw the distinction? If old closed questions have answers then it doesn't make much sense for new closed questions not to have them.

Comment: In all honestly, how many cases are there where a user first votes to close, and then answers the question? And if they really really wanted to, they could just answer first and vote afterwards. The value of this is questionable and impractical :)

Comment: @Rachel - I agree. While I think that the first suggestion makes sense, from an implementation side it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Rachel, I see this pattern very often from *some* users.

Comment: @TravisJ *they should probably not answer the question* - true, but the thing is : *some users do*, and some do it frequently, which IMO makes no sense, unless you are only after reputation growth. The worst part of this mechanism is that even *after* the question was closed, the answer can still be accepted (and the reputation points granted to the answerer).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not in favor of these proposed new rules. While I very rarely answer a question and cast a close vote at the same time, I have done it before, and don't think it should be made impossible.

The main reason is that while we can cast close votes, the close review queue is constantly overloaded. So many questions that *should* be closed are not, no matter if I cast a close vote or not. Unless it's a blatantly horrible question, chances are that my vote will expire before the question gets enough votes.

So facing the fact that questions that should be closed will remain open, there are 3 main possible scenarios:

1. I can write a quality answer. We end up with a mediocre question with a quality answer.
2. It gets no answer. We end up with a mediocre question with no answer.
3. Somebody else sees the unanswered question, and posts an answer.

   a. The answer they post is bad. We end up with a mediocre question with a bad/wrong answer.

   b. The answer they post is good. The outcome is the same as scenario 1.

Which of these 3 scenarios is best for the quality of the site? While none of them are ideal, I would argue that scenario 1 and 3b are probably the best. Some people might prefer scenario 2, since they believe that mediocre questions should not get answers. But since scenario 1 is the only one I can control, it's the only way for me to prevent the otherwise very common scenario 3a.

The only case where I think it might be a good idea to prevent this is the case where a gold badge holder applies the dupe hammer. In that case, they know that the question will indeed be closed, so the above is not a concern.

Now, in reality, I almost always just cast close votes anyway for questions that I think should be closed. And I definitely do that for *very* bad questions. But I don't want new rules that in some cases will stop me from doing what I think is best. If I cast a close vote on a question that I know will never get 5 close votes, I want the option to answer it.

Comment: If the question is amenable to a quality answer, it might be possible to edit it into a quality question, as well. Admittedly, I would be loathe to heavily edit a question to make it fit if it was poor to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Tough to say.

I don't want to make it something that's entirely blanket out there; a user could cast a close vote, forget to retract it, and have it harmlessly expire, and in the meantime, they couldn't post an answer to the question.  Mind you, this is a lot less extreme since you can just retract your close vote, but it feels like the system's getting in the way.

If we made it apply exclusively to those with gold tag privileges, then there's two scenarios to consider:

- Question is closed, but reopened by other means - another gold tag user or the community.
- Question is open, they reply, but find a more suitable answer in a duplicate question later.

In the second case, [I've advocated for just removing the answer at that point](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate#comment155221_286072), as it's more or less noise, and it sends a mixed message about the particular user's decision to cast a **binding** close vote.

The *first* scenario is ***tougher***.  The question was thought to be a duplicate but the community overturned the decision.

At that point, I'd still question why it was decided that the question be closed as a duplicate; someone who's experienced in the tag believed that this question deserved closure, but others in the community didn't.

Y'know, that's not a scenario I'd ever trust an automated system to handle for me.  Who's to say that the community was right over the gold tag person?  Who's to say the opposite?

Questions like that may warrant going into the reopen queue, with a twist - let silver badge users and above review questions and scenarios like that.  There's a lot more of those users with that than the gold tag (and yes, I am painfully aware that those numbers aren't entirely "pure", since a gold tag holder also holds a silver tag), and while they're not trusted with the ability to close dupes with a single vote, they've likely been around enough in that tag to at least do some digging on the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure I've answered and voted to close a few questions in the past. I agree this is a bit odd, but this wasn't completely irrational or self-interested. This was certainly never to prevent someone else from gaining points.

The main cases I have in mind were questions that I thought would be more suitable on Super User (or maybe Server Fault). Once I've read the question and if I'm willing to spend a few minutes helping the asker by providing an answer, I'll do it there and then. While I'm generally willing to spend a bit of time to help others, I'm certainly not ready to spend time monitoring that question and checking whether it has been migrated until it is (and *if* it is); you can wait days for migration to happen sometimes.

I can't remember doing it for duplicate, but I can easily imagine a couple of situations:

- I would answer, and only then be made aware (or remember myself) that there is a very similar question. If I've spent a bit of time writing an answer that is slightly more tailored for that question, I might as well leave it. (Remember, duplicates rarely are 100% *exact* duplicates, sometimes adapting the wording of the answer is useful.)
- I would provide an answer, then after a couple of comments for clarification, the question would be turned into something a little bit different, which would now mostly be a duplicate of another question. Again, the exchange and the path that led from this problem (typically a slightly different error message, or something misinterpreted by the asker) can potentially be useful to others.

Overall, I'm not sure this really is a problem. This somehow also assumes that people who vote to close in that situation do it deliberately to get the points themselves and to prevent others from participating. I don't believe this is the case.

As a side note, sure, there may be a few occurrences of this behaviour, but is it worth adding yet another rule to Stack Exchange? We'll soon have to spend more time on Meta trying to figure out what we're now allowed to do or not, instead of answering questions on the main site, which should certainly be a better use of time for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has personally both answered and voted to close a question on multiple occasions, I think I may be able to give some perspective. For me, the two are not related.

If the user asked as question that I know the answer to, I'm not going to withhold a potential answer from them, just because there's some problem with their question, whether it be a dupe, off-topic, whatever. That seems unnecessarily cruel to me, and I think it's things like this that leave a bad first impression with new users. Sure, maybe they asked a duplicate question, but down-voting them and voting to close and then walking away does what exactly?

Also, with a rare exception here and there, I find most duplicate questions actually have a spin that makes them slightly different. The gist of the question may be the same, but simply sending the user off to see the answer to a similar question doesn't necessarily provide the answer they need. In cases like these, I'll often close as dupe more to consolidate than to simply boot it from the system. In other words, here's the particular answer you need, but the next person that stumbles upon this question might find a better answer for them on the similar question's thread.

Decisions to close, for me, are based on whether the question merits one of the close reasons. If the user provided no code, they're going to get a close vote from me for Off-topic > Why isn't this code working?. However, I might still take a stab in the dark at an answer if I have a good assumption of what's likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also relevant: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

I know that this is an old Q&A, but a similar issue recently came up again [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415621/dupe-closed-question-is-reopened-then-answered-and-closed-again-as-a-different) (where people were abusing their dupe hammer to reopen, answer, and vote to close gain).

By definition, if you vote to close, you think that the question can't (or shouldn't) be answered. If a question can and should be answered, it shouldn't be closed (even if a duplicate); if a question can't (or shouldn't) be answered as written, it should be closed. I really don't see any valid exceptions to that.

While it is true that closing a question as a duplicate in particular also allows it to serve as a signpost, its primary effect is still to prevent other people from adding more answers. (If people want to link similar questions without preventing people from answering it, they're free to do so in the comments or answers).

In my opinion, regardless of whether this behavior is intended maliciously or not, closing a question you answered (or *vice versa*) is still not a sensible action. Voting to close and answering should be mutually exclusive, since that's the definition of a close vote (unless the close voter thinks that they should be the only one who should be allowed to answer).

Answer (score 0):

For things like off-topic, you might well know the answer and also vote to close, and also recommend migration to some other SE site for which you're familiar with the topic rules. Seems odd to say you shouldn't answer in that case, since the answer will migrate with the question, *except* if we say something like, "it's our purpose to dissuade people who post off-topic questions by denying them an answer, not our purpose to get question and answer to the right place".

I suppose you could try to follow the question to its new location and answer it there, but that sounds like hassle and SE didn't get where it is today by making it difficult to answer.

Disabling dupehammer (or putting up a dialogue saying "why are you being weird?") for people who've answered the question makes sense to me: they should instead put their answer on the question they're marking this a dupe of, shouldn't they? If their answers to the two questions are substantially different, maybe they shouldn't be marked as dupes.

However, even there I can see a case for doing it. "Dupe" is generally taken to include, "this question is a subset of that other question". There are probably cases where this question's answer only needs to be one tenth the size of the answers to the question it duplicates. The C++-FAQ essays spring to mind. So writing an answer with just the relevant part of the dupe-answer, *might* be more convenient than commenting to describe which part of the dupe-answer is relevant. I'd tend to settle for the comment, though, unless I'd already posted my answer before finding the dupe.

I've also occasionally wanted to hedge my bets. I'll vote to close, but if the community disagrees with me and thinks it's a fine question then OK, here's my answer. This probably happens less these days, though, since I'm more able to predict the community's opinion.

Closing bugs due to typos seem an obvious case as well where the question should be both answered and closed, quite reasonably by the same person. The solutions to such questions often fit in comments, so we could live without the ability to do both, but an answer's an answer.

In short: there are probably close reasons and situations where banning one person from doing both things makes sense. There are situations where it doesn't. So don't take a blunt instrument to a minor problem, but if there's dupehammer abuse then of course do something specifically about that.

Comment: worth keeping in mind that answers that are migrated along with questions seem to increase chances for asker to get into ban ([system seem to penalize askers of these as usual, non-migrated deleted answered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240660/165773))