# Should I answer a question I've close-voted?

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close, question-quality

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545970/which-tier-does-sonaqube-falls-under) is analogous to "which juicer do I squeeze my apple with?" I.e. it not only doesn't make sense, but it shows a lack of understanding.

I voted several days ago to close it, yet it remains stubbornly open.

I've attempted to prod the user into clarifying the question, without success.

I'm tempted to give an answer that points out that the question approaches the issue from a bad perspective & attempts to re-orient the user's thinking. But

- it wouldn't actually answer whatever it is that's being asked
- I'm concerned it would interfere with the close process

So... should I let it lie or give some response in the form of a not-quite-answer?

Comment: related: [Should users be permitted to both answer and close a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286283/839601)

Comment: If you have a question that needs close votes but will probably go unnoticed in the queue or otherwise due to low traffic and you don't mind to chat, you can drop a `cv-pls` request in the [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/)   chat room.

Comment: If the OP is ignoring your comments, they probably aren't going to listen to an answer that's really just a long comment either. Unfortunately, some users would rather wait and see if someone else comes along to answer rather than fix the question so that the people already looking at it will. There are users that struggle to understand what's wrong with their question but those users put more effort in clarifying that just saying "I edited it, now answer me".

Comment: Maybe you could link the OP to a FAQ, or follow Alexei's suggestion and write a FAQ-like self-answered question that would help this OP and others with similar confusion. (Bear in mind that self-answered questions must still conform to the usual question and answer format of SO). OTOH, it may be hard to help that particular OP effectively, given their poor English skills and high level of confusion...

Comment: Very helpful @rene. I have feared in the past that asking for close votes was somehow asking people to gang up on a question/asker. Nice to know that it's an accepted practice.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam that is valid a concern but our room regulars will not act blindly on every request. Expect push back when you parade a  whole tag in the room or when you target a user multiple times. cv-pls is a *close vote please* not a *close vote or I stab you* so our room can help, but there is not a guaranteed closure once posted.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Since you feel the question cannot be answered, no, you shouldn't answer it.

If you want to provide some guidance to the OP on how they can go about improving their question into one that might be answerable, use comments; that's what they're for.

Answer (score 13):

As [Servy's answers says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348506/477420) - if you voted to close - don't answer.

If you really feel that question deserves an answer - edit the question in shape first, remove your vote and then provide an answer. Or if you sense *awesome and unique* question in the one you voted to close you may ask new self-answered question instead and link to it in comment from the original one (as it may not be the question OP actually have).

---

Note that if as you've said the answer "... **wouldn't actually answer** whatever it is that's being asked" you should not post it as answer anyway irrespective whether you (or someone else) voted to close or not. "Answer" that does not answer the question deserves only downvotes.

Comment: I definitely agree with the first part, but I think the last part depends on how you interpret "does not answer the question".  I think that addressing the root cause in an XY problem or suggesting a different approach rather than directly answering what was asked can be useful sometimes and doesn't deserve downvotes. (Personally, I think an answer like that _does_ answer the question, but I can see how some people wouldn't.)

Answer (score 2):

This particular question - no, you shouldn't.

ANY question - it's possible that OP responded to close votes with rewording the question into an acceptable form, thus it became eligible for anyone to answer and not regard it as junk, and you are then free to answer it even if you first voted to close it. So, if a question has been improved somehow since, you MAY answer that question if you've previously voted to close it.

Comment: If a question *no longer* merits closure in your eyes then you should retract your close vote, at which point you no longer have a close vote on a question you've answered.

Comment: Yes, unless the question has already been closed, then edited and qualified to be reopened.

Answer (score -2):

If you voted to close the question, then ***you shouldn't answer.*** If you want to answer it, that basically means you don't think it should be closed anymore. So if you want to answer it, reverse your close vote and answer it. But if it has been improved or edited since you voted for it to close, then you may answer it still. Hope this helped.