# Downvoting an answer because the question is unclear

Tags: discussion, voting

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665402/how-to-create-a-correlation-matrix-in-r), the OP's intentions are not entirely clear. I have provided an answer based on what I interpret to be the aim, but (I believe) I have been downvoted because:

> "there is no clear indication of the intended output, so no point
>   answering."

I think this is wrong. The help center states:

> "voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong
>   information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information"

I don't think my post qualifies under any of those criteria (unless we *assume* that I have misinterpreted the question, but I think that would be an unfair assumption - I'm pretty confident that I have identified the problem correctly, and I've asked the OP to clarify).

**Was the downvoter wrong to downvote me?**

Shouldn't it be the OP that is punished for lack of clarity in the question, rather than the answer provider? Isn't it nearly always possible for *someone* to misinterpret a question to some degree, and therefore invalidate virtually all posts on the site according to this person's statement?

Surely my post should only be downvoted if it is clearly missing the point (i.e. contains wrong information), not because there is some slight risk that it *might* miss the point.

Comment: A downvoter is only wrong if they vote in revenge or because of who you are.

Comment: @rene so voting an answer based on a coin toss (heads = up, tail = down) is ok?

Comment: You can't know how they reached their conclusion to vote.

Comment: That would be why I wrote "(I believe)"

Comment: @Ell, I agree with this post. But I also think there's nothing you can do about it. The downvoter might be wrong, it happens. You *can* put in a line to explain why you answered, and hope they react positively. I *often* respond to downvoted XY problems improperly stated. If the answer gets accepted, I then go back and edit the question. Good for me (usually get some recognition), good for OP (they get an answer), good for SO (other people find a good Q&A).

Comment: Why are you assuming the person who posted the "there is no clear indication of the intended output" comment also downvoted the answer?

Comment: @Yannis Timing of the actions, and it's suspicion rather than an assumption, I accept it may be wrong.

Comment: Ok, it's been interesting seeing the responses. Ultimately I think I've been hard done by as I was downvoted because I noted in my answer that the OP should ideally give an impression of the intended output, and I think that's unfair - I think the onus should be on the OP to ask a good question. I've been punished for trying to be helpful, being humble enough to accept that I may have misinterpreted the question, and asked the OP to clarify so I can be sure my answer is correct (or delete/edit it as necessary). My main aim with this was to discuss whether it was a sensible or fair down vote.

Comment: @Ell If you want to provide feedback for the question author on how to improve their question then you should be commenting on the question, not posting an answer. Answers are for *answering the question*, not telling the question author that their question is unanswerable due to missing information.  Of course, that you yourself feel that the question is missing enough information to be answered means that, by definition *even you* don't think that you have answered the question. If even you don't think your answer answers the question, then why are you surprised someone else agrees with you?

Comment: If the question is unclear you risk other users voting based on a different understanding of the problem than you had, which increases the risk of someone thinking your answer isn't useful. You can get burned by this when you think the question is clear and it turns out others thought differently; don't sign up for it by answering when you know it's unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downvoting on answers on questions that should be closed is a really common practice. Such downvotes can be cast for many valid reasons, such as:

- The voter felt that your answer encourages people to ask bad questions, because they get answers
- The voter felt that your answer was not an actual answer to the question, since the question was unclear
- The voter felt that you should've identified the question as one that should've been closed, and thus shouldn't have answered.

And some less valid reasons, like:

- The voter just wanted the question to auto-delete after closure, which only happens if there are no positively scored answers (and downvoting reduces the chance of your answer achieving a positive score)

The essence is: this is normal behaviour on SO. Don't answer questions that should be closed. If you do, you have a large chance of getting downvoted. You can read threads like [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/7296893), [Should I answer a question I've close-voted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348505/7296893) and [Stance on answering "bad" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281793/7296893), where the gist is clear: never answer something that shouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the information, interesting to get a good overview of how people are using the voting system - it would be good if the guidelines reflected how the community actually uses it! Learning my way around SO at the moment and always looking to make sure I get it right.

Answer (score 7):

> Was the downvoter wrong to downvote me?

Yes, assuming your assertion is true that they are targeting you, as a user.

But I assume you really want to ask:

> Was the downvoter wrong to downvote my answer?

No, the down voter is never wrong when they assess the content of an answer on its usefulness. If the question is unclear or lack details that causes the voter to believe answers can at best be a guess they have all the reasons to signal that to future readers and you by casting a down vote.

But you're free to take the gamble and use your mind-reading and prediction skills to provide an answer that might be useful. When you're right, the up-votes will come towards you, when you guessed wrong the down voter was right after all.

As with all guessing/gambling games there are pessimists and optimists, those who believe in a high success rate and the non-believers. Depending in which group you are voting might surprise you, YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

> Was the downvoter wrong to downvote me?

This is the wrong question to ask. The help center for downvoting is a *guideline*, not a rule. You can vote however you want unless you're specifically targeting a person. That's forbidden under serial voting rules, but every other use of your votes is acceptable.

So if someone likes to downvote any and all answers to unclear questions that's their prerogative.

In fact, if you felt like it, you could toss a coin and vote the way it came out on posts. Second guessing single votes is pretty pointless since you can't know both who voted for your post and why they did so.

Comment: Regardless of what the rules or guidelines state at present, we can still discuss whether there should be a valid reason for voting. The guidelines certainly suggest that downvotes should be for a reason.

Comment: @Ell No, there's no point discussing "valid reasons for voting". We don't get to decide how other people vote. Voting fraud (incl. targetted voting) is the only exception.

Comment: @Eli Having subjective rules about when it is appropriate to up/down vote is going create a moderation nightmare. The volume of votes is way too high to have rules that require human consensus of wether something is "valid". Sometimes we get a vote we don't agree with, it happens to all of us and I wouldn't spend energy worrying too much about it.

Comment: I agree with this answer but it is worded *too harshly*. This is exactly why *new responders are discouraged*. The simple answer is human behaviour cannot be controlled or moderated, so we have to live with what may be deemed inappropriate decisions. I get revenge downvotes across posts in the space of a few seconds. Now *that* is unquestionably wrong, but despite flagging I can't even guarantee moderators will even correct this *voting fraud* given their workload.

Comment: @jpp Actual vote fraud will always be corrected if flagged. If no visible action is taken it doesn't mean nothing has happened. It just may sit a while, because even moderators have to escalate some forms of vote fraud and CMs are even more busy then the mods.

Comment: @jpp Mind you you're gaining like 300 rep a day so it's not like an insignificant gnat downvoting like a couple posts could do anything to you

Comment: @jpp Moderators cannot correct fraudulent voting. If the automated script failed to catch the revenge downvotes you mention, then an SE employee must get involved. This might explain why you've been waiting for a response for a while.

Comment: @jpp In that case that may have already happened, you have no way of knowing. Moderator messages (which is what these things are done via) aren't visible to anyone but moderators and the user themselves.

Comment: @yannis, thanks - v helpful. If action was taken, I'd expect it to be marked helpful rather than still pending. But not complaining - just interested in process

Comment: @jpp The fact serial voting flags sit for weeks is also partially my fault. I still have ~250 of them pending, so yours might have gotten lost so far in that

Comment: @Magisch No, vote fraud won't always be detected.  It *can't* be.  I can decide because of your comment here, to go to a random answer of yours and downvote just that one answer, purely out of spite, and no possible automated or manual mechanism could determine that my vote wasn't based on the quality of the answer and reverse it.  It is only the more egregious and obvious cases of voting fraud that can even potentially be reversed.  Having some amount of fraud going undetected is merely the price we pay for having the freedom to all have the ability to express our own opinions of a post.

Comment: @Servy Downvoting just one answer of mine for whatever reason you feel fit isn't voting fraud though, in the SE definition of the word. I agree with you in general. But the situation jpp is describing can and will be caught if flagged.

Comment: @Magisch Yes, it is.  Voting fraud is, by definition, voting based on something other than the content of the post.  It just so happens that it is only actually *enforceable* in a smaller range of cases, where there's compelling enough evidence that someone was not voting based on the post's content in order for SE to confidently reverse the votes.  The rest of the cases are instances of voting fraud *that SE simply doesn't have the capacity to detect or enforce*.