# Why was this tagged duplicate and answered by same user?

Tags: discussion

This question was closed as duplicate & answered by same user? Why? That too a user with 136K reps??

[Define variables in switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37552542/464709)

Don't duplicates mean answer is already there? Plus he has just written whatever is there in the duplicate answers.

Comment: Are you saying that the user should delete his highly-upvoted answer? Why? He posted the answer *before* he could find a duplicate.

Comment: I am saying duplicates means answer is already there. And if you are tagging duplicate then do not put same answer.

Comment: Yes. Don't know. Yes. Yes.

Comment: @TZHX so you agree its wrong to do it.

Comment: No; I answered the questions your post asks. Users can pretty much do what they want so long as it's not malicious; and it seems like the answer is a good one, targeted at the question. A reasonable hypothesis is the user answered the question, then found the duplicate.

Comment: @vaultah I find it is bad form to both answer and close a question.  By closing the question you deny others from gaining rep.  You should not be able to answer and have the opportunity to gain rep while also denying that same opportunity to others.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes they are.  Not the accepted answer but the second answer.

Comment: The question should not have been answered by any of the users.  A google search of the title gives [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+variable+in+switch&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS527US594&oq=define+variable+in+switch&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60.335j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and the dupe question is the first result.

Comment: Why... why not ask him?

Comment: I've done this.  It is sad because the SO search when looking for dupes is not very good so Google is better.  If I know the answer I post it and then might Google for some explanation as to why the fix is necessary, etc... Then I see a good dupe and I dupe-hammer it.

Comment: @Will I wanted a general answer not pin point one person.

Comment: @AbraCadaver okay.

Comment: You wanted a general answer to a specific question?  That makes no sense.  If you want to know why person X did thing Y, you cask person X, not people ABC.

Comment: I wanted to know why any person X would do it!

Comment: See, now I have to go open a meta question to ask why someone would start arguing only to immediately demand I stop arguing because it is a waste of time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The obvious answer here is that the answerer didn't realize the question was a duplicate when he wrote the answer.

A quick check of the moderator timeline shows this is true:

[image: "possible duplicate" comment added two minutes after the answer was posted]

Comment: What would happen if he'd known that the question was a duplicate? I'm aware it's very hard to claim something like that but I'd like to know the official policy against that.

Comment: In this case its legitimate and the user didn't intend to just write an answer & tag duplicate. Also his answer is not a copy paste so clearly he doesn't intend to just write answer to a duplicate question.

Comment: @ayhan In general if you notice such a think you may flag the post for moderator attention. And the moderators would look into it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what happened.

Comment: @ayhan: If I had known it was a duplicate, I would have voted to close it and not posted an answer.

Comment: In more detail, I posted the answer, then saw the "possible duplicate" comment (apparently not associated with an actual close vote, and later deleted), then checked the duplicate, then voted to close.

Comment: @KeithThompson I've recently read this discussion (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate) and couldn't be sure if this (knowingly answering a dupe question and then closing it) is considered abuse because the answer seems like a personal opinion. So my question was about what the moderation would do in such a case. Maybe it was wrong to use your case as an example.

Comment: @ayhan: I agree that *knowingly* posting an answer and immediately closing the question would be abusive -- and it wasn't obvious that that I hadn't done that.