# Can a question be up-voted, marked as duplicate and answered simultaneously?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, upvotes

Here is a question [Assigning column names in a data file read by R [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711070/assigning-column-names-in-a-data-file-read-by-r) that was recently asked. The question is

1. Answered by a few people.
2. Marked as duplicate by the same people.
3. And up-voted by someone.

Is it logical to have all the three situations? Is there a case where all these three situations can happen or is it just answered to get some reputation?

Comment: You can answer, flag, upvote/downvote in the same question - I don't see nothing weird in that particular question

Comment: Answering *and* marking as duplicate is a little odd (although I have also done this, when I didn't find the dupe right away), but it's certainly possible to write a good question that's a duplicate (see e.g. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Comment: There is something different in this question I think. Both akrun and Procrastinatus Maximus have gold badges in R. It means akrun could single handedly close the question. Also in the comments akrun says it is not a dupe. Maybe voted for closure than retracted?

Comment: And also related: [Why was this tagged duplicate and answered by same user?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324151/why-was-this-tagged-duplicate-and-answered-by-same-user)

Answer (score 7):

I've done it several times in the past. I get really excited when I see something that I know I can write a good answer for, so I jump in and start writing. I put some effort into it, because I know that answer is going to be what feeds my family the rep that my growing kids need for that week.

Then I post it, notice a close vote and I'm like *oh no!* I then take a look at the proposed duplicate and realize that I answered *that one too*. I chalk it up to being overcaffeinated and go back about my business. I'd have at least 5x the rep that I currently do if I was doing it deliberately.

When you see a *good* answer to an obvious duplicate, it's pretty safe to assume the best of intentions, and folks just being really eager to jump in and answer that they don't think to look. And remember, *good* duplicate questions are good for the site, it helps people find answers no matter how they search - so don't hesitate to upvote a good question if it's a good question.

Comment: You might also want to mention that you diamond mods can merge duplicate questions if the new one has answers bringing something new to the table. And it probably helps immeasurably when the flag contains the action wanted as well as a good rationale.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, why not? You might write an answer, only to realize *later* (e.g. by someone else's close vote) that the question is actually a duplicate. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31696168/4751173) is a case where it happened to me. I upvoted the question because I found it very interesting, and so did a lot of other people; in your case, the upvoter may well be somebody else who didn't answer or vote to close.

Of course, there are some people who deliberately answer easy-to-answer questions which are in fact duplicates (and they know it). There will always be people who try to game the system.

Comment: Thanks!!. As, here different people have different tastes, but I still believe, that it is partiality to down-vote some duple and  up-vote some.

Comment: @AaghazHussain it is partiality, yes. We tend to be very discriminatory towards bad questions. Dupe != bad