# Mjölnir: use guide

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I recently gained the [Java tag gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/java) and with it, the Mjölnir (privilege of closing questions as duplicate with my single vote).

This actually seems *a great power* which *comes* (I'm sure you know `:P`) *with a great responsibility*.

So I was wondering, similar as stated in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate):

**Are there any guidelines on what Mjölnir users can follow?**

---

If not, I propose something (feel free to add, answer to propose or edit):

- Comment and **get OP feedback** before using closing privilege.
- If you're not sure, **wait for 1 or 2 close votes** before yourself vote as duplicate
- **Never answer** a question and after close it as duplicate if you don't mark your answer as community wiki.
- (more)

---

Also, specific tags could have more concrete rules:

- If [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and in the title appears [`NPE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), just **close it!**

Comment: What's the point of having the privilege if you're going to wait for other close-voters / the OP? The whole point of Mjölnir is to be able to close obvious dupes quickly. Preferably, before there's a FGITW answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus agree, but everybody can make mistakes, misundestand a question or simply doubt, having this guideline for this cases I think is better than doing nothing if you don't feel absolutely sure or wrongly closing a question (even it can be reopened)

Comment: I'm less cautious, since I can also single-handedly re-open a question, if the OP explains the closure is incorrect.

Comment: It's generally bad form to [answer a question and then immediately close it as a duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334706/2174085).

Comment: I wonder, would there be any appetite for a feature request where a gold-badge holder could opt out of having the dupe-hammer? I don't feel strongly about it, so would not make such a request myself, but that might be of interest to readers who support the OP's post here.

Comment: *"Comment and get OP feedback before using closing privilege."* why?

Comment: @KevinB In the words of the German philosopher Scooter, in his oft-cited work "Move Your Ass!": "It's nice to be important, but it's more important to be nice."

Answer (score 9):

I've got a gold badge in Java as well, and while there are a few things that you can just look at and close as a dupe, you actually need to take the time to *look* at each question before bothering to close it.

I'm not going to give you any hard and fast rules on what to close and when to close it, since that's up to your discretion and is largely on a case-by-case basis, but it's worth it to you and everyone else to actually do the investigative work to see if the question *really* is a duplicate, or if it's *related* but not answered by the dupe.

Even if you *didn't* have the dupehammer, you shouldn't have voted to close questions as duplicates arbitrarily anyway, so take that kind of thinking into account; this time, know that your vote is binding, public, and will be reversed if it's wrong.

Comment: I'm asking this question because I'm concerned about this. I thought a few rules to myself, but maybe we can make a guideline, getting a gold badge is not easy and you must have wide experience in SO, but having dupehammer feels like I must be **much more** careful than I already was before.

Comment: @JordiCastilla You should be exactly as careful as you were before. If you feel that you need some kind of guidance or rules on using your new privilege, then you were not careful enough previously when you didn't have a binding vote.

Comment: @Stijn IMO that's not true, you can be a good driver with a normal car, but you will drive the same first day you get an F1? that's the same...

Comment: @JordiCastilla You'll still follow the same traffic rules as you did before, won't you?

Comment: nope, F1 must be driven in a circuit....

Comment: @JordiCastilla OK... at this point, making a comparison between voting to close a question and driving an F1 car makes no sense.

Comment: @Stijn IMO I think you don't understan my concern, that's normal, I haven't it till I had the dupehammer, anyway, there are guides at SE for everything, they are not mandatory, just a guide, what you have against that?

Comment: @JordiCastilla part of the problem is "guides" are often interpreted as "laws" and "rules" by less experienced users.  If someone sees their question closed with a dupe hammer and finds a guide that says you should do x, y, and z, they will think their question was closed wrongly and start complaining.

Comment: Even some NPE are nasty and not so easy to understand when they're related to a 3rd party component (missconfiguration/usage). So even something that seems so basic shouldn't be close-dup too fast.

Answer (score 3):

> Comment and get OP feedback before using closing privilege.

So you're suggesting we wait for feedback from the same person that wasn't able to figure out before posting that it was a duplicate, who has a vested interest in keeping their own question open, and in many cases is a drive-by poster who won't ever revisit the post? Sure, follow that rule personally if you want, but don't make it some kind of general guideline.

As other answers/comments have alluded to, why would there need to be any guidelines other than whatever apply to close-as-dup votes in any case?

> If you're not sure, wait for 1 or 2 close votes before yourself vote as duplicate

In many cases the one or two close votes will never come. Or they will come only after some stupid or duplicative answers, or after many users have wasted time looking at the question.

This also implies that you are going to somehow revisit the question on a regular basis to see if the 1 or 2 close votes you were waiting for came in. Perhaps you plan to remember these by writing them on little yellow post-its stuck to your screen? I don't know about you, but I have better things to do with my time.

> Never answer a question and after close it as duplicate if you don't mark your answer as community wiki.

This seems like a solution in search of a problem, and to possibly be based on a conspiratorial view of gold badge holders as malicious rep-hounds that will answer and then immediately close as dup to prevent others from answering. Is there any evidence that this happens with any regularity?

Remember that a hammered post can be easily re-opened, including by yourself or other gold-badgers. So the "damage" from someone misusing or abusing the hammer is limited to a short period of time while the question is closed.

If you are scared of using the hammer in a particular case, then don't use it. Instead, you can leave a comment saying "this might be a dup of that". If you feel that the hammer is being abused in general (an allegation not supported by evidence), then propose that it be revoked.

Rather than putting even soft guidelines in place on the existing hammer, our focus should be on further increasing the quality of the site by extending hammers to e.g. typos, which has been discussed extensively here, but which sadly the community has never been able to coalesce around.

Perhaps it's not the case here, but suggestions such as yours are often rooted in the mentality that closing "hurts someone's feelings" or makes the site more "unfriendly", which I desperately hope we'll get over one of these days.