# Answering a question, then closing an older question as a duplicate of it

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

When is it acceptable to close a question as a duplicate of a newer one that you have just answered?

Here is a concrete example, for the sake of motivation. I had answered [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48966779/2751851), only to immediately after find [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27341956/2751851) (asked in 2014, with an accepted answer from 2015). I felt the question I had answered would be a slightly better duplicate target (as it was more straight-to-the-point). For that reason, I considered hammering the older question against it. That, however, felt a little shady, and the difference was marginal anyway, so I went for the unadventurous option and closed the newer question, while moving my answer to the older one (as it included a tiny bit of additional information).

(One case in which I feel such a closure would be uncontroversial is when the newer question is a purpose-built canonical. Another one would be if the close voter stumbles upon the older question a long time after answering the newer one, and concludes the older question wouldn't be a good duplicate target -- that's why I added the "[...] one that you have *just* answered" qualifier to my question above.)

---

Companion question: [*Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate)

Comment: @Braiam I take your choice of dupe target to mean "it doesn't matter who the involved parties are, even in this case". That is a stance I can easily get behind...

Comment: @Braiam: to be totally meta you should have answered this as well :/