# Is there any guideline on dup hammering questions that already have answers?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

Is there any guideline on [dup hammering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) questions that were already answered?

When there is no answer yet, then it's pretty clear that the question should be closed. But how about situations where the question already received several (upvoted) answers?

My main concern about this is that dup hammering questions with one answer would be favoring the particular user/answer?

Comment: Note that duplicate targets have to have an upvoted or accepted answer as well to be valid.

Comment: Vote early, vote often. The only guideline that matters.

Comment: @JonClements Yes, the duplicate targets does have an upvoted or accepted answer. I am concerned with the timeline of dup hammering.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, my question is exactly how _early_? What if an answer have already published? Isn't dup hammering with one answer would be favoring the particular user/answer?

Comment: @BDL Answer (single) on the question that gold badgers want to close.

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, it's a duplicate. The fact it has 0, 1 or even 100 answers doesn't change that. The only thing it can change is the direction of duplication, the best one needs to be the dupe target.

Comment: @HansPassant The main concern is when the dup hammered question is already having one single answer (gold badger's own answer or some random user's answer).

Comment: Duplicate is a way to drive reader to the best answer. If A is old question with answer.  And B the modern exact duplicate of A. If B's answers are great and have a detailed canonical answer that address all the concerns. A is a dupe to B. No matter the timeline.

Comment: As early as you identify that it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Braiam But wouldn't dup hammering a question with only one answer equivalent to favoring a respective user/answer? That is my concern.

Comment: That's not a concern to have when closing a question. The important part is that no further answers are added in the dupe, and the the signpost now points to the correct target. Unless **you** were the author of said answer, but that was already covered in several answers and comments.

Comment: Is "dup hammering" a real term?  Google sure hasn't heard of it very much.

Comment: @RyanLundy, "Dupe Hammer" is a [thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders). It's a power that comes with a tag gold badge. For a tag gold badge, You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers.

Comment: @RyanLundy dupe from duplicate and hammer because "I have the power!". Kids these days...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, for clarity, the timeline:

- User A posts a question Q1
- User B answers this question Q1
- User C dupehammers this question Q1 as a duplicate of Q2

Then user C is not in the wrong. User A and B are. A for not searching, B for not searching *and* posting an answer.

There being an answer to a question should not limit said question from being closed as a duplicate. Perhaps user B should remove their answer and repost it under Q2, if it isn't already there.

Comment: To be fair, asking a duplicate question is not necessarily _wrong_.

Comment: I don't like the blatant _User A and B are wrong for not searching_. What if they used different keywords for searching?

Comment: @André it's a slight exaggeration to invert the blame the OP is presenting here. As if a warranted dupe-voter is wrong.

Comment: I personally would take it down one notch and say _they can be wrong for not searching_. Sometimes nobody needs to get blamed for anything :)

Comment: If they were not *wrong* then the older question probably should have been voted as a dup.  Relax, the word "wrong" is not an automatic CoC violation.  It has been a proper English word for seven-hundred years.

Comment: @HansPassant Hopefully 'Wrong' doesn't get added to the list of words that, if contained in a comment, a flag to that comment deletes it automatically and gets marked helpful. I feel like people are going really overboard with what feels unwelcoming (This "If *I* can possibly find a way to take offense, it's unwelcoming!" mindset that makes people think words like "wrong" are a personal attack or whatever), and it's really getting out of hand.

Answer (score 6):

Imho, the number of answers on the question to close shouldn't matter at all. If it's a duplicate, close it as such.

But you should take answer quality into account when deciding which question you are going to close as duplicate of which. Closing a question with a great answer as a duplicate of one that just has a code only answer is probably not a good idea.

<sub>Disclaimer: If you answered the question yourself, then you should think twice before dupe-hammering it. Don't actively use the dupe hammer to protect your answers! For guidelines about this, [see this other discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate).</sub>

Comment: Perhaps, the disclaimer part is of immense importance. Now the only answer can be of gold badger's answer as well. So is there a guideline?

Comment: In regard to the disclaimer: If it's a dupe, ___always___ hammer it. If you answered it yourself, remove your answer, and possibly add it to the dupe target if that adds value.

Comment: I'll try to make it clearer what I mean: Don't actively use the dupe hammer to protect your answers.

Comment: for me The quality of the answer should matter..

Comment: @DragandDrop: To determine which one should be closed, for sure. To decide if its a duplicate: Imho, No.

Answer (score 0):

The site mechanics requires that there is at least one up-voted and/or accepted answer to use it as dupe.

Apart from that, the only thing that should matter is the quality of the question and posted answer(s). The *best* post should be preserved, other duplicates should be closed as dupe to that one. Post age doesn't matter. The number of answers doesn't matter. But the number of votes per answer does matter, as an indication of quality.

With this in mind, we should not necessarily close down all new dupe questions immediately. If the present dupes are so-so and not crystal-clear "canonical dupes", it might be wise to keep the new question open for a day or so - even if it's a dupe. Given that the question seems to be good and interesting enough.

Because if the new question starts to attract high-quality answers, the new question might turn out to be a much better canonical dupe than what's already on the site. In particularly if the present posts are outdated because of changes in the programming language etc.

In such cases, the old posts should be closed as dupes to the new one.

The above goes for all dupe closing, not just dupe hammer. But dupe-hammer wielders are probably most suitable to use the above method, since they have the domain knowledge to tell what's good and can also get the job done immediately, without the need of voting.

Comment: (Unless the dupe target is owned by the same user, then the answer restriction doesn't apply)