# How should I treat a well-written question that is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039140/sql-server-join-two-tables-n-a-view-take-rows-from-one-and-turn-into-columns), to my eyes, deserves a lot of credit for being clear, providing good examples, and is pretty much exactly what we want from a new poster.

That said, it's not particularly well-researched, and the problem he is having is a definite duplicate of a scenario already asked and answered on Stack Overflow (searches for `SQL Pivot JOIN` would show several of them).

The poster is new enough to SQL that the lack of technical understanding is completely understandable, though, and based on comments he (incorrectly) assumed he couldn't use `PIVOT` in conjunction with a `JOIN`, and thus wouldn't have realized that it applied to his question.

What should I do?  Should the question be:

> a) upvoted because of good writing
>
> b) downvoted because of insufficient research
>
> c) voted to close as duplicate
>
> d) some combination thereof?

I already left a comment congratulating the poster on their question, pointing them towards other questions and Google phrasings that might help, and letting them know that they might be closed as a duplicate, but I'd like to know how the system should handle congratulating them on the one hand while dealing with the duplicate on the other.

EDIT: Some additional information about the original post:

> 1) The question title is not, in itself, the right way to express what
>   he wants ... my reference above to a Google search represents my
>   understanding of the method he needs, not the OP's.  I know that what
>   he's looking for is a `PIVOT` - he didn't.
>
> 2) The poster had already found posts about the correct answer (in
>   this case, `PIVOT`) but assumed incorrectly that they did not apply to
>   him because most tutorial examples don't include a JOIN.
>
> 3) If the poster had gone a step further and asked Google if you could
>   use a JOIN with a PIVOT, he would have found his answer easily.

Comment: I would vote on the question based on it's content, ignoring the fact that it is a duplicate. I would then of course vote to close it as a duplicate. (i would probably vote to close first and not up/downvote at all though)

Comment: @KevinB The primary factor given for votes on questions is whether or not they are well researched.  It's clearly a very important factor, not an irrelevant one.

Comment: I still wouldn't have wasted a down/upvote either way. Given the structure of the question, i would be comfortable assuming he did in fact research it.

Comment: @KevinB and Servy, edits just made to the post might clear that up a bit - there was some research done, but he (incorrectly) dismissed the solution he found because most provided examples online don't include a piece that was needed, and (as far as I can see) the OP's experience with the software was insufficient to let him realize he could just combine the two.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)

Comment: @Renan, I've read that and believe it is addressing a different concern: my primary question is what do to about a well-composed question that is about a scenario already asked/answered, just written by someone without the technical expertise to find/understand/apply the existing answers.

Comment: @Renan: IMO, tThe question that you referenced is related, but not identical to this question.

Comment: How can a question be a duplicate if you need additional knowledge to know it's a duplicate? It doesn't make sense to say it's a duplicate just because it has the same answer. A proper answer would be to explain how the other answer applies.

Comment: I personally think this is flaw in Q&A system - the best written question should always be the "original" one regerdless of time posted. Meaning if there is better asked question later, previous one (and worse) should be the duplicate.

Comment: I don't care about the answers here. When I come from Google and find a good question or at least a question with the answer I was looking for, then I treat both like the only true things for me. Links to other questions is only additional information. I trust Google **if it comes to Q&A**.

Comment: I agree with @Bitterblue. I think questions easier to search by novice are "well-written". They help everyone looking for answers. Questions like the following is pretty useless for someone dont already know the obscure term https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It should be closed as a duplicate, if that's what it is, and the duplicate question answers his question.

As for voting, at the end of the day that's up to you.  Do you believe that the post was actually useful and helpful?

I personally think that it doesn't matter how well written a post is, if they didn't even take the time to throw their question into Google first it's still just wasting everyone's time and isn't actually helpful, and I would vote accordingly.

Comment: My $0.02: Sometimes a duplicate may only be noticeable by experienced users. Therefore, an question may still be worthy of up-votes in its on right, while being a duplicate. It broadens the chance of pointing future searches in the right direction by providing more keywords.

Comment: @Schorsch If sticking the exact question, word for word, into Google yields the answer then clearly it's *not* using different terminology, and *isn't* any more searchable.  If a duplicate exists *but the person posting the question doesn't appear to have been able to find it* despite searching using the vocabulary he was using *then* the question at least has some potential for being a window into the canonical question.

Comment: @Servy, I should been more specific in my original post:  the Google search I mentioned was what I knew the answer was, not what the OP thought it was.  I put it in as a proof that the question's underlying meaning is a duplicate of questions and answers already on SO, even though the original poster did not use or know the terminology that would have made a search easy.  Nothing in the poster's question referenced the PIVOT keyword until I brought it up in a comment. See edits above.

Comment: @AHiggins At the end of the day you have to ask yourself whether or not you feel a reasonable research effort was made before asking the question.  I'm making no judgement as to this specific question, you simply have to ask yourself whether you felt the person did sufficient research and failed, or simply failed to attempt to put in sufficient research.  The specifics of how you come to such a decision are of course going to be subjective and will vary widely.

Comment: *"if they didn't even take the time to throw their question into Google first it's still just wasting everyone's time and isn't actually helpful"* - true, but a complete noob may not have the experience to express a useful search term. I imagine google brought them to this site judging by their comments.

Comment: @K̨̩̭͚̘̗̻̞͈͖̙͙e̗̦̼̳̣̦͜͡v̢̝̟̗̱̯͉ If they clearly attempted to find a solution and failed, then obviously that wouldn't apply.  That's why I said "**If**".

Comment: I agree with most of this answer... but hey, I do care a lot if a post is well written!

Comment: I agree that it would just be a well written duplicate worthy of closing.

Comment: @AHiggins My question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510061/overload-the-behavior-of-count-when-called-on-certain-objects was marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289705/count-elements-for-objects-implementing-arrayaccess-using-count?lq=1, but my question has way more upvotes. (It's not exactly a duplicate, though.)

Comment: At the end of the day, a duplicate is a duplicate and should be closed.

Answer (score 17):

If the new question is better written than the original and has a better answer than the original then you might want to consider closing the older question as a duplicate of the newer one. If the new question doesn't have an answer but the original has a near perfect one you could flag the post using the "other" option for a moderator to close and merge the old question into the new one.

The ideal situation is that we have the best possible question as the one that's open to answers and all others are closed as duplicates of it.

Comment: Does migrating/merging answer still exist? I haven't seen it done for ages.

Comment: @Bruno - yes merging still exists. But the questions have to be exact duplicates.

Comment: In this case the new question may be a better question, but doesn't have a better answer.  I'd say the answer is generally more important than the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, ChrisF! In this specific case, the original question (and answers) are clearly the best.  However, the question under consideration described the problem in a different way, since the OP did not know the 'right' way to explain the issue.  As such, do the differences in phrasing justify the continued existence of both questions?  Even though the answer is the same, and the scenario is identical, they were described differently, and as such both might help future searchers ...

Comment: @AHiggins - yes. If the new question states the problem in a different way then it should remain. It's another sign post to the correct answer.

Comment: @ChrisF, whoops too late - someone marked it as a duplicate already.  Interestingly, I'm not sure I agree - the post they pointed at follows the same simple (single-table) example that convinced the original poster that it didn't apply to multi-table scenarios.  Should I have commented on that post linking to this discussion?

Comment: @AHiggins - I meant it shouldn't be **deleted**. Of course it should be **closed**.

Comment: @ChrisF, I guess I just displayed my ignorance ... I assumed that a post closed as duplicate would automatically be deleted eventually. Thanks for correcting me!

Comment: I actually prefer this method.  Selecting the clearer question for remaining open is the better option than simply when the questions were asked.

Comment: @AHiggins A primary use of duplicates is to add extra ways of coming across answers from different angles. Good quality duplicates are useful as they hint that another answer isn't showing up early enough in a Google search.