# Automatically link original post to meta 'Specific-Question' post

Tags: feature-request, meta, linked-questions

I recently asked [a Discussion question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267214/how-should-i-treat-a-well-written-question-that-is-a-duplicate?noredirect=1#comment69909_267214) on meta regarding a [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039140/sql-server-join-two-tables-n-a-view-take-rows-from-one-and-turn-into-columns) on Stack Overflow.  While the details aren't particularly important for my question, my Meta post was about whether or not I should vote to close the SO post as a duplicate.

The Meta discussion is ongoing, but during the course of the conversation another user (or users) flagged the SO question as a duplicate.

I've seen examples of [other Meta discussions about specific questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229248/should-an-old-popular-c-static-analysis-tools-question-be-deleted-or-locked) where [someone left a comment on the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635/what-static-analysis-tools-are-available-for-c) linking back to the Meta discussion. That probably would have been smart for me to do as well, but life outside of SO continues, and by the time I thought of it, the post had already been flagged.  Whether or not the Meta discussion would have changed the ultimate result, I wonder if reading the conversation about the post might have influenced those who cast the votes, and perhaps they would have participated as well.

I can't think of any reason why someone reading the original question wouldn't want to know that it was being discussed on Meta, and it might even have helped with the decision to flag it as a duplicate.

Given that, should there be an automatic link between a question and a related discussion on Meta?  There are already several places where similar information is shown:

**This sidebar lists other posts within SO that this question links to (or that link to this question)**:

[image: This sidebar lists posts that this question links to (or that link to this question)]

**This question header shows information about flags placed on the question**:
[image: This header shows the results of flags placed on the question]

**This question footer shows the results of flags placed on the question**:
[image: This question footer shows the results of flags placed on the question]

Could a link to Meta discussions be automatically added to a SO question when a Meta post is created that links to it (possibly limited to just posts with the [specific-question] tag)?