# Psst. We're talking about you over here

Tags: feature-request, questions, meta, notifications

I would like to be notified when a Meta question is asked about a Stack Overflow question I've asked, answered, or commented on.

I'll refrain from suggesting solutions here in order to avoid conflating voting support/disapproval for the goal with support/disapproval for any given design for achieving the goal.

---

**Update 1:** Related questions:  There are two related questions, useful for background but ***insufficient for closing this question as a duplicate***:

1. [Is it possible to know if your question is being discussed on Meta
   Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297264/290085)

   That question asks if it is possible and is tagged a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion).  Answer is that [*there is no automated system that would inform you*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297265/290085).  An answer regarding whether there *should be an automated notification was **not** provided.*  The present question is specifically a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for there to be an automated notification.
2. [Automatically link original post to meta 'Specific-Question'
   post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267241/290085)

   That is a similar [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) but received too few views (37) to gauge interest.  Plus, [the author has joined the conversation to support his request here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313851/290085), and the question is now closed a duplicate of this question.

---

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't already exist but I want to say this has come up as a feature request before.

Comment: Here it is: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267241/automatically-link-original-post-to-meta-specific-question-post

That only got 4 up votes & 37 views though.

Comment: Both BSMP's and gnat's links are helpful for background, but I believe there's merit in leaving this question open as a channel for gauging support for this suggestion specifically as a ***feature-request*** (#1 was not, and #2 didn't get seen).

Comment: Voting to reopen, no need to close a feature request as a duplicate of a discussion when the discussion question does not even address the reasons why the feature is not a good idea.

Comment: Crafty title. Where's all the text about my narcissistic self?

Comment: @KyleKelley You're so vain, you probably think this question's about you, don't you? Don't you?

Comment: "*I'll refrain from suggesting solutions here in order to avoid conflating voting support/disapproval for the goal with support/disapproval for any given design for achieving the goal.*" It's way too early in january for that kind of sentences. My mind is still full of cheese. +1

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Touché.  Just meant to focus first on *should* we do this, letting *how* come later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Let's do this.

I've put up a [similar request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267241/1225845) a year or so ago, after noticing a few situations where users in a review queue took action on a post under Meta discussion. In that request, I've suggested adding an automatic comment to a question referenced by a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag on Meta.
These comments are often manually posted by users from Meta, and it seems that we could save a bit of time/work on their part, and make things more consistent - if doing it manually is a good thing, doing it automatically seems like a better thing.

The benefit would be that anyone who reviews, edits, answers, or votes on the question would have the opportunity to participate in the Meta discussion and take the community consensus into account if they so desire.

Limiting it to the [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag (edit: also the [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer) tag) would mean that questions referenced in comments or answers, or in general questions, wouldn't get the notification - this would only trigger when a question was specifically up for discussion.

Comment: What about [meta-tag:specific-answer]? What about if the tag is added / removed later? Or if the question is deleted / locked?

Comment: Good points. I didn't think about specific-answer, but it seems like the same ideas could apply. I'll edit that in when I'm back at a computer.

Answer (score 114):

Let's not do this.

In many cases, notifying the "victim" that a Meta question is being asked about them is counter-productive.

Imagine for example a hapless newbie struggling to come to terms with the English language, whose question is used as an example for some larger trend in a Meta post.

Or an accusation being made that turns out to be unfounded - an automatic notification would just serve to create unnecessary bad blood. It works *much* better when the complainant gets their first responses from a relatively level-headed Meta audience, rather than also throwing the complainee into the mix right away.

You'll find that whenever it's actually important and productive for a user to get notified about a Meta discussion, someone is almost always helpfully providing the link already, without an automated system.

That has worked fine so far, no need to "fix" it.

Comment: More common than the subject of a Meta post being a "victim" requiring protection would be, I believe, the case where a normal poster would simply want to know that further conversation exists, without having to rely on the kindness of another user manually informing them.

Comment: @kjhughes my experience is that the kindness is pretty reliable. I've seen too many cases where it was a good thing that someone's complaint was first responded to by uninvolved Meta users, rather than the complainee themselves.

Comment: I acknowledge the potential dampening benefits of supporting only manual notification by another concerned user.  Thank you for this insight.  I cannot say with certainty, but something still leads me to favor letting the subject of the discussion make that determination rather than others.

Comment: @kjhughes I see your point of view.

Comment: How about making this an "opt-in" thing (preference option)? 99% of all users (including those "hapless newbie[s]") probably wouldn't even come across the option this way.

Comment: I agree with your stance. Still, I need to point out two things. First one being that I'm skeptical to "*relatively level-headed Meta audience*". Second one being that, in my experience, no matter what I do to screen out OP, they still get in somehow, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558667/whats-operator-supposed-to-mean-for-a-string) (the comments below the question). But all things considered, it works immensely better than any other alternative I know of. SO I **do agree** with you.

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's same-site, where it pops up as a linked question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm afraid I don't follow. What I mean was that I asked a question **based on** a comment in another question. It wasn't **linked** or **referred**. Yet, somehow, the guy noticed that and kind of made me his lady dog (although very respectfully and in full dignity - it was mostly amusing to get "caught").

Comment: @KonradViltersten "[...] [the comments section](/) [...]" counts as a link.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 So natively stupid... Sigh... I guess my statement's still valid. "*no matter **what I do** to screen out*" but it's because I'm too dumb to think of those details, hahaha. If I said "*no matter what **one does***", then it wouldn't work. Admittedly, I got lucky this time, hihi. Goof point, mate. Happy 2016.

Comment: To avoid the "hapless noob" problem, just make a minimal rep, say, 100, before this feature kicks in. Seems there is little down side to providing this...unless you actively want to hide discussion of someone's post, which goes against the grain of...everything.

Comment: @KonradViltersten I think it was totally worth it if just for Jon Skeet's edit;)

Comment: What is the acceptance condition for this having 'worked fine so far'? Is it simply that this has been the status quo and the universe has not come to an end?

Comment: It seems your main complaint with the suggestions is that "newbies" would be able to see Meta posts which point out their not-so-good behavior.  Might I suggest that this would work if SO only granted certainly high privileged people this power?

Comment: @John my worry affects users with any level of rep really. Imagine a user asking "why did this high-rep user do xyz? Isn't this discouraged?" it is *much* better for the  Meta community to handle it first (and, say, explain  why the behaviour the user is calling out is acceptable after all because such and such thing) instead of having the accused user be notified, and of course feel obliged to defend their honour, right away. It's just a huge potential for unnecessary conflict. If it turns out to be a justified accusation, someone should manually notify the user who is being talked about.

Answer (score 31):

If [we tracked links cross-site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/display-other-se-site-links-in-the-linked-questions-sidebar), this would be almost free (as would a bunch of other useful things). But we don't, which means this isn't free and would probably require much of the same expensive plumbing that resulted in *that* request getting shot down.

Which sucks.

But that doesn't stop you (or anyone else) from adding links manually when applicable. If you see a post being discussed here on meta, post a comment under it with a link back to the meta post. It's easy, cheap, and allows you to personalize the link in cases where it might need a bit of introduction.

Comment: Are links available in the data dump in such a way, you could do it with an SEDE query and associate a link from a meta post with the original SO post and author?

Comment: No, unless by parsing manually

Comment: This is a discussion of the difficulty of implementing the feature, not the desirability of the feature.

Comment: @EricJ. The difficulty of implementing a feature will influence the decision whether or not to accept the feature request. So this is actually relevant input to the discussion.

Comment: Would the same challenges apply to adding an automated comment to the post being discussed?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. It'd be a little bit simpler since there'd be no call to *track* these links; once the comment exists, it stays there. The flip side is it could get really noisy.