# Are "This question is discussed on meta" comments useful?

Tags: discussion, comments

I noticed there is a trend where most of the SO questions being discussed here on Meta result in someone adding a `This question is being discussed on meta` comment, optionally linking the meta discussion.

Are this kind of comments useful? Do they try to explain why the post has that many upvotes or downvotes?

And not lastly, should we flag these kind of comments?

Do we need this kind of information to vote objectively? Will a comment like that make us think twice before pressing the vote up/down buttons?

Comment: I think they are. They let people know that their actions are being discussed in another thread somewhere, giving them a chance to go and add their opinions. For the sake of transparency I even think these comments should be encouraged and definetely not flagged.

Comment: They are very useful. They are not so much about explaining the amount of votes but to make sure that the discussion just happens at one place. From the point where a meta question exists, discussing the same topic under the original question does not make sense anymore. They are also important to inform people who are going to close/delete/reopen-vote about the reasoning why the original question is closed and to a possible consensus how the question can be made on-topic.

Comment: RE Your edit, yes we should all vote based on quality. Which is exactly what a lot of people do when they get linked to something on main from meta. The problem is that it often isn't high quality questions that get linked here. But all that aside I fail to see what that paragraph has to do with someone linking *to* meta *from* main which is that the title and the rest of the question seems to be about.

Comment: @ivarni there is a connection between linking from meta and adding a comment on a question linked from meta, this is the reason for the edit. It's related to the question I asked.

Comment: @ivarni and regarding this "The problem is that it often isn't high quality questions that get linked here" - this could indicate that Meta has become a propaganda tool for people wanting to close/delete questions.

Comment: @Cristik for couple years I'm on SO I don't remember even single case on Meta where OP comes and complains about *upvotes*, questions by OP about *downvotes* are almost daily occurrence... Even that set of question  alone skews ratio toward not-so-stellar questions being linked from Meta.

Comment: Well, that's a bit of a logical leap. Low quality content ends up here because most people don't have much need to discuss unproblematic content.

Comment: @ivarni the question is about the need of adding such comments "This question is discussed on Meta". I mean, do we need this kind of information for us to vote objectively? Will a comment like that make us think twice before pressing the vote up/dow buttons?

Comment: BTW, I replaced the last paragraph with my last comment :)

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374966/).

Comment: @gnat: Not an exact duplicate, that one is a FR for a notification, this one is about manually added comments.

Comment: @ivarni That should be an answer....

Comment: [Google search for those comments](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%2Fquestions+%22discussed+on+meta%22+-%22meta.stackoverflow.com%22)

Comment: @user202729 I generally don't post answers on meta. I'm expressing my opinion and not giving authoritative answers. I'll leave that to more experienced users or mods.

Comment: @ivarni Meta is for posting opinions right? (when the OP asks for them, not e.g. when they ask a mod why they deleted a question like the recent meta post) Besides, posting answers as comments can be considered "cheating" - they cannot be downvoted, and (in this case) they're pinned to the top *before* the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are this kind of comments useful? Do they try to explain why the post has that many upvotes or downvotes?
>
> And not lastly, should we flag these kind of comments?

From the help center:

> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - [...]
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

I'd say that a meta discussion counts as "relevant but transient information".

However: The link is not useful once everyone (which curates the question) have seen it, and a consensus is settled. Therefore, ***once a consensus is settled, it can be deleted***.

---

> Do we need this kind of information to vote objectively? Will a comment like that make us think twice before pressing the vote up/down buttons?

People can vote in whatever way they find appropriate (as long as it's based on content, not user)

Answer (score 35):

These comments are useful for the following reasons:

1. They let the people under discussion to know that there is a discussion about them (or their actions), and to defend themselves if they want.
2. They allow readers of the post to be aware of the discussion, so that they can participate. This is important because a tag's followers have often different opinions than the general meta readers.
3. They help explain the meta-effect votes (as you said in the OP).

I would even like the comment to be added automatically when something is linked from meta.

Comment: I'm 99% agreeing with this, but the automatic link is a no-go. There are several reasons for linking to posts that have nothing to do with a post being discussed. It might as well just be a link to some examples of a situation.

Comment: Good points. I would like to add a 4th bullet: to notify users/moderators moderating the post. For example, in case there is a discussion about if a question is to be considered on-topic, we shouldn't start some close/re-open war but rather let the meta discussion take place, after which we can close/re-open accordingly. (Preferably the final moderation in such situations should be handled by a diamond moderator.)

Answer (score 14):

I'd say **yes**, these comments are useful to let the user know where the sudden activity on their question comes from.

Just picture this. You've posted a question in 2011 about something deemed on-topic back then, got a couple upvotes and a good answer. Now, 7 years later, you suddenly retrieve downvote after downvote. Turns out somebody created a meta question "Should we encourage *x* type of questions?" with a link to your question where the general consensus is "no we shouldn't". It'd be nice to know where these downvotes are coming from. I've done this firsthand, where a +6 question got to -10, closed and deleted because of my Meta question.

Comment: The main purpose is not to explain sudden votes though, but to invite the poster and everyone else involved to participate, explain their actions or learn how to improve.

Comment: @Lundin that's debatable. As for myself or any other frequent meta visitor, I would want to participate in the debate. The same cannot be said for a random visitor who posted one question back in 2014 to solve a homework problem who lost the privilige to comment because their question got metavotes.

Comment: The discussion is obviously to be carried out on meta, not in the comment field on the main site.

Answer (score 10):

Yes.
Discussion on meta usually means some controversy on discussed post. Like someone wants to rollback some edit while someone else wants to keep the edit. When I know there is some discussion on meta I will not perform any action on this post (like flagging for moderator attention or performing rollback) until this discussion gets resolved.

Answer (score 6):

> Are this kind of comments useful? Do they try to explain why the post
>   has that many upvotes or downvotes?

Yes, they are useful, and not only to passerby readers (who indeed can vote or edit based only on the post quality) but also to the OP and those directly interacting with them, by comments, edits or answers.

> And not lastly, should we flag these kind of comments?

No, there is no need to flag them. People want to know if their actions are discussed on Meta and there is even a well up-voted [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313839) to automatically add them.

> Do we need this kind of information to vote objectively? Will a
>   comment like that make us think twice before pressing the vote up/down
>   buttons?

Maybe, but that's not the main purpose of this kind of comment.