# Is it better to mark similar questions as a duplicate or answer the question?

Tags: discussion

I've come across many questions that are not an exact duplicate of an existing question but are similar and had the original poster read the original article, he would likely have his question answered.

In these cases, is it better to rework the original answer as a new answer on the new question or is it better to mark it as a duplicate?

Comment: I suppose that would depend on the amount of difference between the two and if the new one would be helpful to others.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions