# How can we improve the c# tag to properly clean up of duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, voting

This is a very common scenario in the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag:

Someone posts a rather simple question, it quickly gets one or two answers (usually very brief answers) that just “show the code” without explaining much. Far too often, these kind of answers come from high-rep people, including those who have a gold badge for the tag and could close-hammer them immediately.

Someone—for questions that I stumble upon that’s usually me—then bothers to look for a duplicate because it’s obvious that such a question cannot be the first one. Meanwhile, those super concise answers already got hit by the momentum of the C# tag and accumulated a few upvotes (usually around 2). Then, approximately one or two minutes later, I *finally* find a duplicat target and close the question (luckily I have a gold tag).

So usually, this would mean the question is “over”, people can stop thinking about it and OP only needs the duplicate target to actually figure out an answer themselves. But the upvotes keep coming, like crazy (it’s not unheard of that answers on a closed question receive upvotes in the tenth). This all wouldn’t be so bad if the answers would be *good*, but usually, it’s just a FGITW who quickly posted code that “works”.

---

Let’s take an example from earlier: I find a simple question on [how to sort a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573449/sort-list-in-c-sharp-based-on-inner-list). Easy enough, there should be a good duplicate around. I do a quick search and find one immediately that is good enough (imo). I close it and apparently with my close vote, there slips an answer through. It’s a single-line answer of unformatted code, without any explanations or anything—a pretty low quality answer, so I downvote it.

While the answer is receiving more and more upvotes, it even comes to this point:

[image: Five upvotes and 4 downvotes]

Five upvotes and four downvotes, on a objectively poor answer to a question that has been already closed as a duplicate. And this was many minutes after the question was closed.

Meanwhile, I’m being challenged in the comments that the duplicate target is not good since it sorts in the wrong order (OP mentioned that they want to sort descending). I remember there was some meta post before that basically said that it doesn’t matter whether the duplicate target is the perfect fit for the question, as long as the (obvious) duplicate question is closed. Unfortunately, I don’t find that meta post right now, but I’m not concerned that I handled incorrectly here: The question is a clear duplicate, and I believe we should expect users to actually work with proposed solutions instead of expecting perfectly working code for their explicit requirement.

---

Anyway, situations like these are *very common* on the C# tag. Or at least, I see them *very often*. I am not used to this behavior from other tags where I frequent, most prominently the Python tag which has a strong community behind it that tries very hard to keep the question pool clean.

The saddest thing is that very often, high-rep and gold-badge users participte in this poor behavior of posting bad answers to simple questions when there are multiple easy to find duplicate targets.

What can we do to improve this situation? How can we educate users to care more?

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)

Comment: `The saddest thing is that very often, high-rep and gold-badge users participte in this poor behavior of posting bad answers to simple questions when there are multiple easy to find duplicate targets.`  You don't get lots of rep by voting to close questions, you get lots of rep by posting answers to questions.  That people taking actions that are harmful, but result in them getting lots of rep, have lots of rep, shouldn't be all that surprising.

Comment: @Servy that problem should go away soon (now that you don't even have to answer questions to get a lot of rep;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå That’s an interesting question, although it seems a bit unrealistic to me that it will change anything in the short term. I’m particularly worried about the C# tag community since it’s just very extreme there. I’m hoping that we can somehow educate the users that regularly watch that tag to stop upvoting bad answers.

Comment: @Servy That’s very true, but then there’s the side of people that keep upvoting those answers too. Why do they do that? Especially when the answers are obviously poor?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think that's the first good think I've heard coming from Documentation; it gets (some of) these people off of SO proper.  Thanks; I needed that pickmeup.

Comment: @poke Most people don't actually upvote posts based on how useful they are, they upvote them if they're not actively abusive, or if you're really lucky, if they're not clearly incorrect.  It's hard enough getting people to downvote answers that are just wrong, let alone answers that are correct but unhelpful.

Comment: More [information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/4751173) about the Stack Overflow demography.

Comment: If this doesn't get one or two real quick answers before being closed as a dupe then I'll be very disappointed meta.SO.

Comment: Maybe we should award rep for being the first to propose a dup on a VTC ;)

Comment: Why not use the C# room to try and build that strong community like Python has?

Comment: It needs enough users that are willing to moderate. That is all. With enough hands the CVQ would be empty. That said: there is a spin-off from SOCVR at the moment that has the focus on finding duplicates:[SOCVFInder](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/socvfinder). That room exists to ping gold tag dupe hammers when a duplicate is found. It now still relies on comments that are left on a post but if you can get enough folks to at least leave the *possible duplicate* comment, c# dupe hammers can respond. That should help a bit, not with the upvotes but with getting stuff closed.

Comment: @rene As this question points out, it's just faster to post a low quality answer than it is to find a quality duplicate, at least in lots of cases.  Even if you spot a question within seconds of it being posted, know it's a duplicate at a glance, and have a gold tag badge, the odds of someone else sneaking an answer in there before you can close it are rather high.  Given that, no amount of more people willing to moderate will really solve this; it might handle a few cases here or there, but it won't make more than a dent in the problem.

Comment: @Servy following that reasoning the only option is a server-side duplicate check but this question is tagged discussion and not feature request. We're not going to reach those FGITW types with a post on meta, let alone change their behavior ... so you still need more people but what those people have to do is open for debate  ....

Comment: @Servy the only thing you can do is to propose a policy that is a "harmful behavior" and then use that to ban people that dedicates their time to systematically answer those questions... or you know, voting to delete more duplicates.

Comment: @Braiam Deletion doesn't really do much.  Even if you delete *half* of these questions, if it works half the time, and you lose nothing the other half, it still earns you rep to do it.  You need to delete pretty much every single instance of this for that to be a reasonable deterrent.  Possible, but not practical.

Comment: *This is a very common scenario in the c# tag* should be *This is a very common scenario*. Sad, right?

Comment: All "gamification" features of SO stacked against closing as duplicate - so as long as this did not change I doubt there will be visible change in behavior.

Comment: I'm getting fed up of having arguments with users (often high and very high rep users) about closing as dupe rather than answering. There's just no incentive to close questions. Maybe even a single rep point for being part of a successful closure would be enough to help, at least people would then perceive that it's worth their time.

Comment: @DavidG or that all gains where simply stripped away by deletion of the question.

Comment: @Braiam Well they are stripped away provided the question isn't really old. However without the incentive to close the questions they will never be picked up by the roomba. Also, if any answers have positive scores, the also prevents the roomba deleting them. The leaves the job to the community to cast delete votes.

Comment: @DavidG wasn't that what I'm saying? Use your delete votes on these useless dupes.

Comment: @Braiam But that requires a user to cast a close vote, wait for potentially 4 more people to vote too, then to cast a delete vote (if they have the privilege.) It's just too much effort with virtually no reward.

Comment: @DavidG but at least you are doing *something*. Try not to think of the material rewards and more in the reward that a sane and healthy collection of questions under your tag means.

Comment: @Braiam But I do think of that, the problem is that most (virtually all?) others only care about those magic internet points and for them, that trumps having a clean site.

Comment: @Braiam Just for perspective, it required this meta post to get that linked question (and its answer) to a negative score. If that didn’t happen, there would have been no chance for deletion. And deleting the posts is only a possible fix much later after everything bad has already happened.

Comment: @DavidG *“I'm getting fed up of having arguments with users about closing as dupe rather than answering.”* – Same, and it’s even difficult to actually argue about it because everything is spread over meta. There should be one collective post someone could link to and say “You and your actions are wrong, here is why”.

Comment: We will close close to 175 to 200 c# questions today with a little more help on deck. In the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290)  room via independently reviewed lists. The average day sees about 73 closed if we are not organized and don't do this.