# Answering dupe questions--how to reduce the noise?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Similar to [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions)

Prompted by [JS 2 decimals after coma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60342260/438992)

As an often-asked question (regarding both FP and JS formatting) which still received an answer (likely started during de-duping), when the new answer doesn't add anything to the discussion, what's the recourse?

Just hoping the author deletes it seems insufficient. Can't (legitimately) downvote the answer, because it's right. But it adds needless noise--when there's a dupe (IMO) the first action of both the OP and people that get to the dupe via a search should be to make clicky on the dupe.

What's the solution?

Comment: Daily dose of irony: a "too many comments" flag on a question asking how to "reduce the noise". The conversation that was here has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208279/discussion-on-question-by-dave-newton-answering-dupe-questions-how-to-reduce-th). :-)

Comment: It's not noise for visitors, which are not logged in. They are directly forwarded to the duplicate target by the system.

Comment: @Trilarion it's only the case if the question has no answer. The issue is to have the duplicate answers, not the duplicate questions

Comment: @TemaniAfif Then it's noise for everyone.

Comment: Maybe we should follow a statistical approach. If there are already sufficient duplicates of a question we start deleting a few of them - those with lowest amount of visitors or lowest amount of combined answer scores.

Comment: *Can't (legitimately) downvote the answer, because it's right.* Sure you can, if you don't think the answer adds anything useful [to the site as a whole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202897). If something has already been answered many times, does posting the same thing again contribute anything useful? You might not think so, in which case the condition for the downvote tooltip is fulfilled.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The link makes some valid points--I'll think about it.

Comment: in addtion to what @CertainPerformance said, if you downvote such answers they have a high chance to get deleted immediately because users giving such asnwers are looking for Rep and getting the -2 will scary them so they will run to delete their answers. I do this a lot and it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can ask for the question or the answer to be deleted on a moderation chat room like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: or maybe it's *really* time to consider a delete queue

Comment: @Temani But delete votes aren't very abundant, are they? How many do you get a day at your rep level?

Comment: @yivi I get 30 per day which is a good amount to be spent on a queue

Comment: @Temani Yeah, 30 sounds like reasonable amount. I get 6 or 7.

Comment: I get 5. I hardly use them, though. Mainly only old stuff or really bad crap.

Answer (score 3):

This is too long for a comment. *(And this turned into an essay, I apologise, I probably went off topic and I humbly accept your downvotes)*

Personally, I think that the site is as much at fault here as the users (both those asking and those answering) are. I also think there are few "pros" to answer dupes and there are certainly "cons" to answering them. Here are a few paragraphs on my thoughts on why:

### The Site

For the answerer
The Search facility on Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) isn't great for those who are asking a question. This isn't a "fault" of the search facility, per say, but for new users it doesn't help them. Experienced users of the site know that the Search function is better for looking for questions with specific tags and keywords, not for looking for questions and answers.

Let's take an example from [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) (as that's where you find me). Something that people are always asking is how to split delimited lists into its individual items in T-SQL. This is probably asked at least twice a day in one of the related tags.

So, let's take a "normal" search pattern: *"How do I split a delimited list into rows in SQL Server?"*. That brings you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+do+I+split+a+delimited+list+into+rows+in+SQL+Server%3F) in Stack Overflow, which *does* give you [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722833/2029983), which does actually address the issue. The next results, however, are [What's the fastest way to perform large inserts with foreign key relationships and preprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20896114/2029983) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42709015/2029983) on a question called "SSRS Comma-delimited list as Parameter value". Very little to do with the problem.

Now to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+How+do+I+split+a+delimited+list+into+rows+in+SQL+Server%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). First result is the question [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5493510/2029983), which is **[Highly Active Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)**. Great! Because it's so active, it has a wealth of answers too! Then we have [Splitting delimited values in a SQL column into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11018076/2029983) and 3rd our question from the SO search.

All the links from Google are relevant, and so a lot of information can be consumed. As **Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows** is highly active, it has a lot of answer, and a lot of information available as well. For the SO search, however, only the first link is useful, and then you're straight onto unrelated content.

---

The site doesn't have a clear goal/opinion on what to do with a dupe. If you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates it says that users can vote for dupes, but it doesn't say anything about that users *shouldn't* answer them; it's not "against the rules", so why not?

---

The site doesn't really stop users from posting duplicates. I have seen topics created with "no a dupe" in the title, because title's need to be unique. Unsurprisingly, the question is duplicate of the question with the title they tried to use (which I often find when editing out "not a dupe"). The site should be trying to lead users to resources better that appear to answer their question. Yes, it prompts them with some questions, but nothing forces them to review it, so it simply often isn't effective.

### The Askers

Something that many of the active users feel is that a significant number (from my experience) of questions lack research efforts. This *is* a problem, and it is also my most common reason for my downvotes. Some (new) users do research, and these are great questions, but also they are unlikely to be duplicates.

Often even a small amount of research can get a user to find the duplicate they end up having their question closed with. This is honestly, in my opinion, an attitude problem of said users. "Ask and you shall receive", but this is a "**profession**" environment, with professionals doing to bulk of the answering. So us some effort, and we'll show you some too.

---

Closing as a duplicate is seen, by some, as "unfriendly" and "not answering the question". This is so far from the truth Flagging as a duplicate *is* answering the question as it's pointing the user to the answer that already exists. If the user is failing to implement that answer, then they should be asking a question with attempts; that's a debugging question, not a "how do I do this" question.

Unfortunately, a lack of effort to research normally is closely related to a lack of effort to implement, and why these users are "upset". The answer doesn't give them the answer they need "exactly"; they need to change the object names, and so it "doesn't answer their question. For a user with this type of attitude, however, there is little you can do as they don't have the intent to learn, only to receive.

### The Answerers

Some users don't care about duplicates at all, if it's an opportunity for "internet points" then it's fair game, and the question should be answered, no matter the simplicity of the question, the number of other existing duplicates, or the presence of a well known high quality duplicate within the tag. Users that are newer won't know about the latter, but "gold badges" will. There are certainly some "Gold Badgers" I'm aware of that I have never seen close a question as a dupe, and will answer questions that are duplicate candidates frequently.

---

Like users that don't put in effort research for their question, answerers do the same too. If a question is quick to answer, but there's certainly a dupe candidate out there, then an answer is what some will do. Sometimes it takes a few attempts to find the *right* duplicate to a question, and by the time you do, writing the answer is far quicker. Therefore some choose the "quick" route.

### Pros

Answering a dupe gives the user who asked *their* answer, unique to their problem. This is a good user experience for that user.

### Cons

Having every *unique* version of a question means that information is harder to consume. If you want to find out a range of solutions, but need to consume 10 questions, with 12 answers, which each ask a variation but still the same problem, you're unlikely to consume that well. Having to swap tabs/windows and reference the question the answer is addressing makes it difficult for you to fully comprehend the answers in comparison to each other.

---

It doesn't promote evolutions of answers. There are some questions that are 10+ old that are continuing to get answers as technology evolves. This is a *good* thing. You end up with a question that answers multiple versions of the same product. Take one of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5493510/2029983) I shared before, which was asked in 2011. That has answers that were relevant then, in 2012 onwards and 2016 onwards. Each evolution also means those using older technology can use the parts relevant to them. If there was a separate question for each version (of SQL Server in this case) finding the right one could well be hard. Easily when things like Google will push "popular" pages to the top of their algorithm.

### ***What is the solution?***

TL;DR there isn't one. Sorry. There are no guidelines on not to answer duplicates, so you can't stop people doing so. You shouldn't vote those questions down either (if they are correct). Downvoting is for when answers aren't useful. *I have, however, downvoted users that give the same answer to multiple questions and just cater the object names for the question. In some cases, I flag as well.*

The best you can do, is flag it as a dupe, or vote to close it. If you feel you should, downvote the question as well, if it's clear it lacks research. At best, the user will learn to look next time. At worst they keep doing it and get a question ban.

For the answerers, unless a rule comes in about (not) answering dupes, the those who answer them will continue to do so. End of story.

Comment: I shall humbly distribute my downvote :P -- just kidding. I need a TL;DR for this whole thing so I can read later and understand.